# What's wrong with my string reversal function? (C#)

Tags: c#

```
char[] a = { 'o', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e' };

for (int i = 0; i < a.Length/2; i++)
{        
  a[i] = (char)(((uint)a[i])|((uint)a[a.Length-(i+1)]));
  a[a.Length-(i+1)] = (char)(((uint)a[i])^((uint)a[a.Length-(i+1)]));
  a[i] = (char)(((uint)a[i])^((uint)a[a.Length-(i+1)]));
}
```

I know how to implement this using standard .NET functionality and temp vars. I am just curious what specifically I am doing wrong in the above example that causes it not to work when the following works fine:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;

a = a | b;
b = a ^ b;
a = a ^ b;
```

Isn't the above string version just a series of those?

Comment: You can just write char[] a = "orange", I believe.

Comment: I was trying to extend the standard OR/XOR/XOR int swap to a string. That's all it is.

Comment: What's wrong with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string-in-c-20 and http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2006/03/19/9350.aspx ?

Comment: you are using c# so leave this C-based syntax.

Comment: Ben: Thanks; there's another good one in the second link. I'm still curious why this doesn't work though since a single int swap with no temp works using OR/XOR/XOR.

Comment: My eyes! The goggles! They do nothing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hehe, there's no such thing as an OR/XOR/XOR swap - it should be a "triple xor" swap.

```
int a = 8, b = 10;
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

I don't see why you want to use it (aside from the novelty value)

Comment: (And it was just novelty value) :P

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's not working is that you're using a bad example. You can't swap two values by using OR then XOR then XOR. It only worked in your example because 5 and 10 have no bits in common, so the first OR doesn't destroy any information:

```
a = 0101 #5
b = 1010 #10
# step 1 (OR into a)
a = 1111
b = 1010
# step 2 (XOR into b)
a = 1111
b = 0101
# step 3 (XOR into a)
a = 1010 #10
b = 0101 #5
```

But it won't work if they have any bits in common - let's try with 13 and 10:

```
a = 1101 #13
b = 1010 #10
# step 1 (OR into a)
a = 1111
b = 1010
# step 2 (XOR into b)
a = 1111
b = 0101
# step 3 (XOR into a)
a = 1010 #10
b = 0101 #5
```

Note that we now have the values 5 and 10 still, even though we started with 13 and 10. What you're looking for is a thrice-XOR swap:

```
a = 1101 #13
b = 1010 #10
# step 1 (XOR into a)
a = 0111
b = 1010
# step 2 (XOR into b)
a = 0111
b = 1101
# step 3 (XOR into a)
a = 1010 # 10
b = 1101 #13
```

Answer (score 2):

It's destructive (because of the bitwise OR).  Why not use a temporary variable in your loop instead of the exclusive ORs:

```
int tmp = a[i];
a[i] = a[a.Length-(i+1)];
a[a.Length-(i+1)] = tmp;
```

In answer to your second part, what you were doing in binary is:

```
a = 0101;
b = 1010;
a = 0101 | 1010 === 1111;
...
```

When you OR the two values together, you destroy the original numbers.  It works with 5 & 10 because none of the bits are common between the two numbers.  When you do this with the following:

```
a = 0110;  // 6 (base ten)
b = 1010;  // 10 (base ten)
a = a | b; // this is now 1110, or 14 (base ten)
```

You can not recover 6 and 10 again, because OR was an irreversible operation.  Exclusive-OR is reversible.

Comment: What's the fun in that? =) I certainly can do it with a temp var. I was just trying to work out the non-temp var version for kicks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this is not the point of your question, but how about just:

```
 char[] a = { 'o', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e' };
 a = Array.Reverse(a)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out the correct solution using XOR operations... This isn't exactly an answer, but I thought I'd point you that the [`Interlocked.Exchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.exchange.aspx) method is very suitable for this sort of task. (It performs the swap as an atomic operation and therefore works across threads, though that seems irrelevant here.) Nonetheless, I would almost always consider it the simplest/most elegant solution for swapping two variables.

Here's an example of how to use it with the code you posted.

```
char[] a = { 'o', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e' };

for (int i = 0; i < a.Length/2; i++)
{        
    a[a.Length-(i+1)] = Interlocked.Exchange(ref a[a.Length-(i+1)], a[i]);
}
```

Hope that helps, even if it isn't specifically an answer to your question...

Comment: Interesting. It is good to know about the Interlocked.Exchange. It may come in handy in the future. Thanks Noldorin!

Answer (score 0):

```
List<char> characters = new List<char>();

characters.AddRange("string".ToCharArray());

characters.Reverse();

string reversed = new string(characters.ToArray());
```

Comment: I'm just wondering why this works:

int a = 5;
int b = 10;

a = a | b;
b = a ^ b;
a = a ^ b;

But the above code does not.

Comment: You got lucky - 10 and 5 don't have any bits in common.
Try 10 and 8, for example.