# System.IndexOutOfRangeException : Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#

I have the following array:

```
public string reArrange(string s)
{
    char[] array = s.ToCharArray();
    int length = array.Length;
    char[] arranged = new char[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        int newposition = length - i;
        arranged[newposition] = array[i];
    }

    return new string(arranged);
}
```

But the above method raises the following error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

So what might be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `i` is zero, you access the array at index `newposition` which equals `length`; that's one beyond the last valid index for the array, which is `0` through `length-1`.

This will fix the problem:

```
int newposition = length - i - 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Say the length is 10 characters.
On the first iteration of your loop, newposition = 10 - 0 = 10.  This index is out of the bounds of the arranged array.

Also, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string-in-c-sharp-2-0) about reversing a string.  From that post...

```
public static string Reverse( string s )
{
    char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse( charArray );
    return new string( charArray );
}
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to the "better" way to reverse.  =)

Answer (score 1):

You are going to far,

```
for (int i = 0; i < length-1; i++)
```

Comment: but in this way i can not reach the last element in the array ...

Comment: It should be `i = 1` to `length` instead of `i = 0` to `length - 1`

Comment: ah, missed the second array access

Answer (score 1):

```
public string reArrange(string s)
{
    char[] array = s.ToCharArray();
    int length = array.Length;
    char[] arranged = new char[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
       int newposition = length - i - 1;
       arranged[newposition] = array[i];
    }
    return new string(arranged);
}
```

Comment: but in this case i will not be able to reach the last elemnet in the array[]

Comment: The last element in the array is at index `length - 1`. Let's say the array has a length of 3, at `i = 0`, `newposition = 3 - 0 - 1 = 2` (length - 1), at `i = 2` (length - 1), `newposition = 3 - 2 - 1 = 0` at `i = 1`, `newposition = 3 - 1 - 1 = 1`, covering all the valid indexes

Comment: if the array lenght is 5 then using (i < length -1) i will never reach the array[4]!!!

Comment: oops, typo, editing now, thanks