# Changing position of words in a string

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have a string let say,

```
string temp1 = "25 10 2012"
```

but I want this,

```
"2012 10 25"
```

what would be the best way of doing it. format will always be like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to reverse a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string)

Comment: Do you always want to reverse a strngs or reverse word order??

Comment: @PLB yup format is always fixed

Comment: Are you sure you are no looking for DateTime parsing and/or formatting?

Comment: Nope, as I was getting string not date from a method I can't make changes to.

Comment: @Ignacio: Kris asked if you want to change a date format that comes as a string.

Comment: @TimSchmelter if thats the best option then why not :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like its a date. You can parse the string to DateTime, using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) and then use .ToString to return formatted result.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(temp1, "dd MM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.Write(dt.ToString("yyyy MM dd"));
```

*You may use that DateTime object later in your code, and also apply different formatting (if you need)*

Answer (score 2):

try this split string and reverse array , and this will work for string of any length ...

```
string[] myArray = temp1.Split(' ');
 Array.Reverse( myArray );
string reverse =string.Join(" ", myArray );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using the Split command and then recombining the sub strings:

```
String[] subStrs = temp1.Split( ' ' );
String   final   = subStrs[2] + " " + subStrs[1] + " " + subStrs[0];
```

Comment: @PranayRana: Well he states in his comments that the format is always the same ...

Answer (score 1):

So you want to split words and change the order, you can use LINQ:

```
var words = temp1.Split(' ');
String newWord = string.Join(" ", words.Reverse());
```

or if you don't want to swap all words but only swap the first and last word:

```
String first = words.Last();
String last = words.First();
String newWord = first + " " 
                 + string.Join(" ", words.Skip(1).Take(words.Length - 2)) 
                 + " " + last;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a RegEx or split the string and rejoin it in reverse order.

```
string s = "2012 10 25";
string[] tokens = s.Split(' ');
Array.Reverse(tokens);
string final = string.Join(" ", tokens);
```

Answer (score 0):

If Your string has always 10 character (with spaces), You can do the following:

```
string str = "26 10 2012"
str = str.Substring(6, 4) + " " + str.Substring(3, 2) + " " + str.Substring(0, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use string.split(" ").reverse().join(" ").

You can use split, this function will split your string to array on white space as condition then reverse the array and re join based on white space

```js
let string="25 10 2012";
let output=string.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");

console.log(output)
```