# Reversing a string c#

Tags: c#, string

I have this method that gives me IndexOutOfRangeException, can you guys help me to understand why?

```
public string FlipString(string inTxt)
    {
        StringBuilder outTxt = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = inTxt.Length; i > 0; i--)
        {
            char ch = inTxt[i];
            outTxt.Append(ch);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(outTxt.ToString());
        return outTxt.ToString();
    }
```

The method has to be written like this (without the exception)

Comment: String indexes are *zero-based*.

Comment: There is a linq method to do reverse: http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/CSharp/StringReverse.html

Comment: Here's a way of doing it using `Array.Reverse`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string

Comment: Why does it have to be written like this?

Comment: Your code is correct but as indicated string indexes are zero based. This means that the last index in the string array is `string.Length - 1` Thus, your for loop should initalise as `for (int i = inTxt.Length -1; i >= 0; i--)`. Not the `-1` and `>=`.

Comment: Keep in mind that a .NET Char is not an "actual character" (grapheme), but a Unicode UTF-16 code unit. If you reverse a string simply by reversing the order of the Chars, surrogate pairs and combining characters will not be processed correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays in C# are 0-based, not 1-based. You are iterating from `n` to 1, but you need to iterate from `n-1` to 0:

```
for (int i = inTxt.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

On the other hand, if you just want to reverse the string, there's a simpler solution using LINQ:

```
var reversed = new String(inTxt.Reverse().ToArray())
```

Comment: I now that there is a lot better/easier ways to do this but it have to be written like this

Comment: @user1789325: I thought as much, which is why I also answered your original question instead of just providing an alternative. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

to reverse jus try this

```
string reversed = new string(stringinput.Reverse().ToArray());
```

or

```
string input = "hello world";
char[] inputarray = input.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(inputarray);
string output = new string(inputarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public string FlipString(string inTxt)
{
    StringBuilder outTxt = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = inTxt.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        char ch = inTxt[i];
        outTxt.Append(ch);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(outTxt.ToString());
    return outTxt.ToString();
}
```

You need to make your first entry into the loop be for the length of your string - 1 as the string array is zero based.

Answer (score 0):

Extension method:

```
public static string Reverse(this string source)
{
    char[] arr = source.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(arr);
    return new string(arr);
}
```

and using:

```
var reverted = source.Reverse();
```

p.s. keep it simply as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string FlipString(string inTxt)
{
    StringBuilder outTxt = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = inTxt.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        char ch = inTxt[i];
        outTxt.Append(ch);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(outTxt.ToString());
    return outTxt.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start from the last character, that is the length of the string minus 1 because the string is Zero based.

```
public string FlipString(string inTxt)
    {
        StringBuilder outTxt = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = inTxt.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            char ch = inTxt[i];
            outTxt.Append(ch);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(outTxt.ToString());
        return outTxt.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexes in strings begin in 0 and get to Length - 1.

First operation is

```
char ch = inTxt[inTxt.Length]
```

So your code should be

```
public string FlipString(string inTxt)
{
    StringBuilder outTxt = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = inTxt.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
         char ch = inTxt[i];
         outTxt.Append(ch);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(outTxt.ToString());
    return outTxt.ToString();
}
```