# Reverse a string with accent chars?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, .net-4.0

*So I saw Jon's skeet [video](http://vimeo.com/7403673) and there was a code sample :*

There should have been a problem with the `é`  - after reversing but I guess it  fails on .net2 (IMHO), anyway it did work for me  and I did see the *correct* reversed string.

```
char[] a="Les Misérables".ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(a);
string n= new string(a);
Console.WriteLine (n); //selbarésiM seL
```

But I took it further:

In Hebrew there is the "Alef" char : `א`

and I can add punctuation like  : `אֳ` ( which I believe consists of 2 chars - yet displayed as one.)

But now look what happens :

```
char[] a="Les Misאֳrables".ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(a);
string n= new string(a);
Console.WriteLine (n); //selbarֳאsiM seL
```

There was a split...

I can understand why it is happening :

```
Console.WriteLine ("אֳ".Length); //2
```

So I was wondering if there's a workaround for this kind of issue in C# ( or should I build my own mechanism....)

Comment: [TextElementEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textelementenumerator.aspx) might be useful here.

Comment: So `א` is two `chars`?

Comment: You should add this as answer Michael. Was just writing there's no such thing in .NET... Good job.

Comment: @Jodrell, actually, if you paste Misאֳrables in Visual Studio editor, set the cursor on left of the אֳ character, and press the right key, you will see it goes directly to the a, instead of the r. It also has problems going left (stays blocked during one keypress)...

Comment: On the _Misérables_ thing: With accented letters such as the French `é` there might be two or more ways to encode them in Unicode. Either as **one** single code point which holds the entire accented letter, or as a simple `e` followed by one or more non-spacing "combining" accent characters. So if you want to get a "problematic" `Les Misérables` string, start with either `string m1 = "Les Misérables".Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);` or `string m2 = "Les Mise\u0301rables";`. Before reversing, the accent is over the `e`. After careless reversing, the accent goes over the `r`, that is `ŕ`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem is that `Array.Reverse` isn't aware that certain sequences of `char` values may combine to form a single character, or "grapheme", and thus shouldn't be reversed. You have to use something that understands Unicode combining character sequences, like [TextElementEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textelementenumerator.aspx):

```
// using System.Globalization;

TextElementEnumerator enumerator =
    StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator("Les Misאֳrables");

List<string> elements = new List<string>();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    elements.Add(enumerator.GetTextElement());

elements.Reverse();
string reversed = string.Concat(elements);  // selbarאֳsiM seL
```

Comment: Just to clarify, is it `ToCharArray()` that is unaware of these sequences, or is `Array.Reverse()` where the problem begins?

Comment: @DerekHunziker: `Array.Reverse` is the problem.

Comment: I would say the problem is the definition of `Char`.

Answer (score 10):

If you made the extension

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ToTextElements(this string source)
{
    var e = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(source)
    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return e.GetTextElement();
    }
}
```

you could do,

```
const string a = "AnyStringYouLike";
var aReversed = string.Concat(a.ToTextElements().Reverse());
```