# how to check if a string has a newline,then do something

Tags: c#, windows, string

I've got this code,which is going to reverse a text input.  It doesn't capture newlines, so I want to check each time whether we encounter a newline in order to insert a newline in my result string manually.

How is it possible?

```
var a = textBox1.Text;
var c = Environment.NewLine;
string b = "";
foreach(var ch in a)
{
   if (ch.ToString() ==c)
      b += c;
   else
      b = ch + b;
   b += "\n";
}
textBox2.Text = b;
Clipboard.SetText(b);
```

Comment: Is the TextBox multi-line?  I don't think a single line TextBox will take a carriage return.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508203/best-way-to-split-string-into-lines

Comment: That code does not reverse text. Try it with `Aéo`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029238/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Split` to get all lines, then reverse each line.

```
String a = textBox1.Text;
String result = String.Empty;

String[] lines = a.Split(new String[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

foreach(String line in lines.Reverse())
{
    // inverse text
    foreach(char ch in line.Reverse())
    {
        result += ch;
    }

    // insert a new line
    result += Environment.NewLine;
}

// remove last NewLine
result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);
```

**Exemple :** In entry, if you have :

```
test
yopla
```

result will be :

```
alpoy
tset
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question has the following components:

- How to break a string down into lines (handling the fact that line breaks might be represented as `\n` or `\r\n`).
- How to reverse a given line, properly dealing with unicode complexities including [surrogate pairs and combining characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRary/8k5611at%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

The following extension methods handle both tasks:

```
public static class TextExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> TextElements(this string s)
    {
        // StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator is a .Net 1.1 class that doesn't implement IEnumerable<string>, so convert
        if (s == null)
            yield break;
        var enumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(s);
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            yield return enumerator.GetTextElement();
    }

    public static string Reverse(this string s)
    {
        if (s == null)
            return null;
        return s.TextElements().Reverse().Aggregate(new StringBuilder(s.Length), (sb, c) => sb.Append(c)).ToString();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> ToLines(this string text)
    {
        // Adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508203/best-way-to-split-string-into-lines/6873727#6873727
        if (text == null)
            yield break;
        using (var sr = new StringReader(text))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                yield return line;
            }
        }
    }

    public static string ToText(this IEnumerable<string> lines)
    {
        if (lines == null)
            return null;
        return lines.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, l) => sb.AppendLine(l)).ToString();
    }

    public static string ReverseLines(this string s)
    {
        if (s == null)
            return null;
        return s.ToLines().Reverse().Select(l => l.Reverse()).ToText();
    }
}
```