# How to reverse an array using the Reverse method. C#

Tags: c#, arrays, reverse

For some reason when I apply the reverse method, nothing changes.

```
public static string ReverseString(string word)
    {
        char[] myArray = word.ToCharArray();
        myArray.Reverse();

        string ans = string.Join("", myArray);

        return ans;
    }
```

Comment: `myArray = myArray.Reverse();`

Comment: It returns a new array, it doesn't change the original

Comment: Use Array.Reverse() to reverse in-place

Comment: For a version of this method that works with Unicode combining characters, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15029238/1127114

Comment: Array.Reverse(nameOfArray);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Array.Reverse(myArray)` instead of `myArray.Reverse()`.

You are confusing [Enumerable.Reverse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [Array.Reverse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) methods.

`IEnumerable<char>.Reverse`: Returns a new reversed array without changing the old array

```
myArray = myArray.Reverse();
```

`Array.Reverse`: A Void method that will reverse the input array

```
Array.Reverse(myArray);
```

Comment: Yep, that's worked great thank you

Comment: @Callum You are welcome

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you're confusing the method you're using with the *static* `Array.Reverse`, which is indeed a `void` method?

[Array.Reverse Method (Array)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

---

The one you're using is a LINQ extension method of `IEnumerable`, whose reference you can find here:

[Enumerable.Reverse Method (IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

---

For your specific case though, I'd use this oneliner:

```
return new string(word.Reverse().ToArray());
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that myArray.Reverse() does not modify myArray. This method returns a IEnumerable of char with the reverse of myArray.

Try this:

```
var reversed = myArray.Reverse();
```

And then work with reversed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the return value in a variable:

```
var reversed = myArray.Reverse();
```

This is the signature for `Reverse()` method you are using, by the way, this is an extension method in the `Enumerable` class:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Reverse<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source);
```

See the return type is an `IEnumerable` so you will need to store that and then work with that.

You can just do this:

```
public static string ReverseString(string word)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(word) ? string.Empty 
        :  string.Concat(word.Reverse());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method [`Reverse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497(v=vs.110).aspx) is a method that returns a new array (or collection) based on the original items.

```
public static string ReverseString(string word)
{
    char[] myArray = word.ToCharArray();
    myArray = myArray.Reverse().ToArray(); //<-- Call ToArray() method to convert back to the array and execute the deffered action.

    string ans = string.Join("", myArray);

    return ans;
}
```

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate
>   return value is an object that stores all the information that is
>   required to perform the action. The query represented by this method
>   is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its
>   GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For
>   Each in Visual Basic.
>
> Unlike OrderBy, this sorting method does not consider the actual
>   values themselves in determining the order. Rather, it just returns
>   the elements in the reverse order from which they are produced by the
>   underlying source.

Answer (score 0):

You should do `Array.Reverse(myArray)`