# Trouble understanding foreach

Tags: c#

**For each problem**

```
char[] charArray = zig.ToCharArray(); //puts each character in zigs in an array
Array.Reverse(charArray); // Reverses the array 

foreach (char zigArray in charArray) 
{
    Console.Write(zigArray);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

This block works how i want it to but i don't understand why i need a for each statement here. I am confused why i shouldn't just do console.write after i have reversed the string.

(I am following a tutorial)

Comment: Try doing it your way and see what happens. The beauty of programming is that if you have a different idea- you can try it out and see if it works.

Comment: _We_ wont know why you need a foreach statement either.  It depends on what the tutorial is trying to teach you.  A `foreach` loop is pretty essential in C#, its for iterating over something (usually a collection of some sort).  You should try your `Console.Write(charArray)` and see what happens, then ponder the differences between a `char[]` and a `string`

Comment: Please be aware that `Array.Reverse(string.ToCharArray())` [does not reverse strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029238/).

Comment: Fire your tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: try it!

I did. The answer: there is none. The end result on the screen is the same, however, a minor detail, the reversed string is now a character array which makes it a little harder to see what happens right away.

Calling `Console.Write` on an array of chars outputs the text as expected and reproduces the exact samen result as `foreach` does (and not `System.Array` or something like that you might see when printing an `object`).

Why did they use `foreach` then? Probably to learn you how iterating over a collection works. I guess it is just a bad example, move on.