# PowerShell - Reverse a string that includes emojis

Tags: powershell

I've written this below.

It successfully reverses a string without garbling up any emoji characters.

The only trouble is that it doesn't reverse the emojis which is what I was hoping to do.

#### Here's the code I have with some examples:

```
Function Out-ReverseString {

  [cmdletbinding()]
  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = 'Passed string to reverse')]
    [string]$StringInput
    )

  $returnedNewClip = -join[regex]::Matches($StringInput, '([^\x00-\x7F]+|.)', 'RightToLeft')
  return $returnedNewClip

}

Out-ReverseString -StringInput "'What ‍‍ is this?' ‍‍ "  # Returns:  ‍‍ '?siht si ‍‍ tahW'
Out-ReverseString -StringInput ".sijome ekil  I"        # Returns: I  like emojis.
Out-ReverseString -StringInput ". ekil t'nseod ?néiuQ¿"      # Returns: ¿Quién? doesn't like .
Out-ReverseString -StringInput "195981348903269-335"           # Returns: 533-962309843189591
Out-ReverseString -String "¿Quién doesn't like ?"            # Returns: ? ekil t'nseod néiuQ¿
```

Comment: Emojis are two characters each (surrogate characters).

Answer (score 3):

The problem, as commented, is caused by the fact that emojis are multi-byte characters.

Cat Face with Tears of Joy Emoji U+1F639 in UTF-8 are F0 9F 98 B9.

Hugging Face Emoji U+1F917 in UTF-8 are F0 9F A4 97.

To reverse a multibyte character string, one needs to use a grapheme aware iterator, which understands that an emoji consists of several bytes unlike the usual latin alphabet. There's [TextElementEnumerartor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textelementenumerator?view=net-5.0) which does exactly that. Iterate the string with it to get graphemes, not raw bytes, and reverse the result. There's an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15029493/503046), let's convert it into Powershell like so,

```
# Load the globalization assembly for later use
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Globalization
$str = "'What ‍‍ is this?' ‍‍ "
$se = [System.Globalization.StringInfo]::GetTextElementEnumerator($str)
$ll = @()
while($se.MoveNext()) { $ll += $se.GetTextElement() }
[array]::reverse($ll)
$rev =  $ll -join ''
$str
'What ‍‍ is this?' ‍‍ 
$rev
 ‍‍ '?siht si ‍‍ tahW'
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that. Where did you test this because in PowerShell ISE I get ` ‍‍ '?siht si ‍‍ tahW'` The `‍‍` aren't joined to get the `‍‍`.

Comment: @Ste Powershell Core 7.1.0 on MacOS.

Comment: With 5.1 is ISE on Windows I get those above. I wonder if something has changed with those methods since.

Comment: @Ste If you run it on command line version of Powershell instead of ISE, does it work any better?

Comment: When I pate this `"'What ‍‍ is this?' ‍‍ "` I get `'What ???????? is this?' ???????? ????"` so the command line doesn't understand those characters.

Comment: I've tested this exact code in a 7.1 portable build of PS and it returns the correct result. It's the line `[System.Globalization.StringInfo]::GetTextElementEnumerator($str)` which in 5.1 doesn't recognise the `‍‍`.

Comment: 5.1 needs utf8 *with* bom encoding in the script.

Comment: @js2010, sorry I missed your reply. Yes, utf8 with bom is what it's saved as.

Answer (score 2):

Powershell 7 has an enumeraterunes() for strings:

```
$emojis = ''
$a = $emojis.EnumerateRunes() | % { "$_" }
-join $a[$a.length..0]
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I'm using 5.1. That's a great answer otherwise.

Comment: `EnumerateRunes()` enumerates Unicode codepoints and not Unicode graphemes so it won't work for composing or joining, only for simple multi-bytes characters like you showcased.