# Reverse order of characters in every entry in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList with a number of entries, and I want to reverse the order or the characters, so if my code looks like this:

```
public class Test {

ArrayList<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>();

aa.add("hello");
aa.add("goodbye");

(reverse them in some way)


}
```

Then what I want the ArrayList to contain is:

```
olleh
eybdoog
```

I've only managed to change the order of the entries in the entire ArrayList with Collections.reverse, but that really doesn't do what I want to.

Comment: It's actually not the same thing.  The OP wants to keep the order of the arraylist elements, but wants to replace each element with that element reversed as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty version - changing the `Strings` inside the original `ArrayList`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < aa.size(); i++) {
    aa.set(i, new StringBuilder(aa.get(i)).reverse().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`StringBuilder` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (mutable strings) contains a reverse operation that switches the characters of the StringBuilder.

```
int size = aa.size();
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(aa.get(i));
    builder.reverse();    //reverse the StringBuilder
    aa.set(i, builder.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a linear time implementation, modifying the list in place.

```
public void reverseStr(List<String> theArgs) {
   for(int i = 0; i < theArgs.size(); i++) {
       String s = theArgs.get(i);
       theArgs.set(i, new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString());
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

do it like this:

[Best way to reverse a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var aa = new List<String>();

        aa.Add("hello");
        aa.Add("goodbye");

        var x = from s in aa select Reverse(s);

        foreach (var c in x)
            Console.WriteLine(c.ToString( ));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string Reverse(string s)
    {
        char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArray);
        return new string(charArray);
    }
```

Comment: Is this C#? I guess the question has been tagged under Java.