# A Faster Way To Reverse A String?

Tags: c#, pointers

Below is the fastest code I could create for reversing a String

```
public static void ReverseFast(string x)
{
    string text = x;
    StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = text.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        reverse.Append(text[i]);
    }
      Console.WriteLine(reverse);
}
```

I want to address every bottleneck in this equation to make it as fast as possible. The only one I can find so far is the Array Bounds check which I only partially understand. Is there anyway to disable this as I understand it if you use `.Length` the compiler decides not to check the bounds but if you are decrementing as I am in the `for` loop it still does the boundary check? Can someone convert this to use pointers for me which would avoid the boundary check, I would like to test the speed difference for strings in the range of 100k+ characters.

Based on the comments and posts below this is what I have come up with so far.

```
public static void ReverseFast(string x)
{
    StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder(x.Length);
    for (int i = x.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        reverse.Append(x[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(reverse);
}
```

This above solution is way faster than the suggested duplicate question answer. This question is really addressing reversal in the range of 5000 * 26 characters +. I would still like to test this out using pointers to really see if there is no bottleneck especially with such large amount of characters.

Comment: That is **not** going to be your bottleneck. Seriously.

Comment: Initialize the StringBuilder with the correct length (text.Length) - this will prevent the buffer from being resized.

Comment: My question is sort of begging to explore the pointer alternatives in c# and to critique my current idea.

Comment: Replacing `new StringBuilder()` with `new StringBuilder(text.Length)` should get rid of all the unnecessary memory [re]allocations.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3047997/11683) in the duplicated question provides a solution with pointers. Don't stop at the accepted answer there, look through all of them. Although for big strings you might want to remove the `stackalloc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a pointer based solution:

```
unsafe String Reverse(String s)
        {
            char[] sarr = new char[s.Length];
            int idx = s.Length;
            fixed (char* c = s)
            {
                char* c1 = c;
                while (idx != 0)
                {
                    sarr[--idx] = *c1++;
                }
            }

            return new String(sarr);
        }
```

Getting rid of the array index (sarr[--idx]) the following might be faster:

```
unsafe String Reverse(String s)
        {
            char[] sarr = new char[s.Length];
            fixed (char* c = s)
            fixed (char* d = sarr)
            {
                char* c1 = c;
                char* d1 = d + s.Length;
                while (d1 > d)
                {
                    *--d1 = *c1++;
                }
            }

            return new String(sarr);
        }
```

Comment: Nice approach; I benchmarked it, and it is still slightly slower than a flat `Array.Reverse` - I don't claim to know why; but very nice

Comment: Edit: clarification for that - it seems to depend on the string length; for small strings, the `Array.Reverse` seems *slightly* faster; for large strings the pointer code seems *slightly* faster - not enough difference that I'd say either is a clear winner

Comment: I didn't like the index based array access because that involves adding pointers everytime - now it's pointer only...

Answer (score 14):

```
var arr = x.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(arr);
return new string(arr);
```

Note, however, that this will reverse any unicode modifier characters (accents, etc).

Benchmark:

```
Array.Reverse: 179ms
StringBuilder: 475ms
```

With:

```
static void Main()
{
    string text = new string('x', 100000);
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    const int LOOP = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++)
    {
        var arr = text.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(arr);
        string y = new string(arr);
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Array.Reverse: {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++)
    {
        var reverse = new StringBuilder(text.Length);
        for (int j = text.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            reverse.Append(text[j]);
        }
        string y = reverse.ToString();
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("StringBuilder: {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

If we try a string of length 500 and loop 500000 times:

```
Array.Reverse: 480ms
StringBuilder: 1176ms
```

I also tried adding `unsafe` into that, i.e.

```
fixed (char* c = text)
{
    for (int j = text.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        reverse.Append(c[j]);
    }
}
```

this made no difference whatsoever.

And I added in JeffRSon's answer too; I get:

```
Array.Reverse: 459ms
StringBuilder: 1092ms
Pointer: 513ms
```

(for the 500 length x 5000 iterations test)

Comment: is that definitely faster? curious as to how much...

Comment: @Mitch well, I can't see any way it could be slower; the `StringBuilder` needs to do *at least* as much allocation, with the disadvantage of a: probably being oversized, and b: possibly needing a resize; the loop is just a basic loop. I guess it depends on whether `StringBuilder` is happy to give you its private `string` (if it is an exact size match). That's for the OP to test, I'm too busy.

Comment: Sorry I thought the question was "A Faster Way To Reverse A String?" Don't we usually tell people to benchmark? ;)

Comment: I benchmarked it on my machine a few times and at 100k+ characters this is definitely slower on my machine. For any normal operation I am sure this is fine. Just not a faster way to reverse a string as Mitch pointed out.

Comment: @CodeCamper 100k benchmark added; much faster

Comment: @MitchWheat happier now?

Comment: Strange on my machine I got 
Array.Reverse: 543ms
StringBuilder: 107ms
Array.Reverse: 247ms
StringBuilder: 111ms
Array.Reverse: 163ms
StringBuilder: 130ms

Comment: @CodeCamper ah, it could also be .NET Framework version specific; `StringBuilder` has had lots of changes over the years. I'm targeting .NET 4.5; you? I've tested on both x86 and x64 - that can be important too. For me the `Array.Reverse` approach was still fastest on both for small (500 etc) strings. For very large strings (100000) the pointer code was *slightly* faster (not enough to dance about)

Answer (score 2):

Set the capacity when you create the `StringBuilder`, that way it doesn't have to grow during the loop and allocate more memory. Assigning the parameter to a local variable is an unnecessary step, as the parameter is already a local variable.

```
public static void ReverseFast(string text) {
  StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder(text.Length);
  for (int i = text.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reverse.Append(text[i]);
  }
}
```

That is just the basic steps to remove any unneccesary work. If you really have a performance problem with the code, you would need to analyse what the generated code does, and possibly create different versions that do different things depending on the current framework and hardware.