# How do I find the palindrome of a number?

Tags: c#, palindrome

I already wrote the part of the program that reverses the number:

```
        int n = 0;
        n = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        double l = n;
        double reverse = 0;
        while (left > 0)
        {
            double r = left % 10;
            reverse = reverse * 10 + r;
            l = l / 10;
        }

        double final = n + rev;
```

However, if the final double does is not a palindrome, I want the program to add the final to its palindrome, and keep doing that until the a palindrome is found. The problem is in the the conditional statement.What condition should I give to the if statement?

Comment: Don't use doubles, for one thing. Just stick to `int` since that's your input.

Comment: I think [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number#Lychrel_process) is what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string)

```
bool isPalindrome(String s)
{
    char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse( charArray );
    return s.equals(new string(charArray));
}
```

Do the palindrome check on the string. If it's not a palindrome, convert the string to an int, add whatever you want, convert it back to a string, repeat.

Avoid working with `double` in this application. Stick to `int`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just reverse the string rather than treat it as a number:

```
using System.Linq;

var N = textBox1.Text;
var reversedN = new string(n.Reverse().ToArray());
var result = Convert.ToInt32(reversedN);
```

Comment: This is much better than my previous while loop. Very helpful.