# Reverse Single String value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have wrote this extension function to reverse the single string value. I think I can short it more please suggest.

```
public static string ReverseSingleString(this string value)
        {
            string newString = string.Empty;
            char[] chars = new char[value.Length];
            char[] chars2 = new char[value.Length];
            int j = 0;
            foreach (char c in value)
            {
                chars[j] = c;
                j++;
            }
            j = 0;
            for (int i = chars.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                chars2[j] = chars[i];
                newString += chars2[j].ToString();
                j++;
            }
            return newString;
        }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to reverse a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any reverse function:

```
string Reverse(string s)
{
    char[] c = new char[s.Length];
    for (int i = s.Length-1, j = 0; i >=0 ; i--, j++)
    {
        c[j] = s[i];
    }
    return new string(c);
}
```

obviously you can put that in an extension method

Answer (score 4):

How about following extension

```
public static class StringExtensions{
   public static string ReverseString (this string value) 
   {
       var reversed = string.Join("",value.Reverse());
       return reversed;
   }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like homework to me, has probably been told not to use Reverse() :-)

Comment: not a homework but ask me not to use Reverse() function create your own :)

Comment: Why would someone ask you to create your own if its not a homework? Time is money...

Comment: interviewer man, just figuring out how would I... so want to know am i going right way or wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Since it's an extension and i don't need to care about readability, i would use a `StringBuilder`:

```
public static string ReverseSingleString(this string value)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.Length);
    for(int i = value.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        sb.Append(value[i]);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use [`Array.Reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
public static string Reverse(this string source)
{
    var chars = source.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(chars);
    return new String(chars);
}
```