# Reading a string in reverse

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to read a text file in reverse. I have the following:

```
StreamReader readtext = new StreamReader("log.txt");
string readmetext = readtext.ReadToEnd().Reverse();
```

Yet it gives me an error saying:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  c:\users\nat\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\windowsformsapplication1\windowsformsapplication1\orders.cs  23  33  WindowsFormsApplication1

How would I fix this?

Comment: Have a look at the following thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns `IEnumerable<char>` try this, first convert it to char array then create new string:

```
string readmetext = new String(readtext.ReadToEnd().Reverse().ToArray());
```