# Anyone knows more simple way to make Reverse and take first and last letter?

Tags: c#

As you can see i use start index from arr[0] and arr.last();
but anyone can suggest another way to do the same thing more simple?

---

```
    public static string F(string s)
    {
        char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(arr);

        if (s.Length >= 2)
            return new string(arr)[0] + "" + arr.Last();
        else
            return s;
    }
```

Comment: On reversing strings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this, you don't need `Array.Reverse`:

```
public static string F(string s)
{
   if (s.Length >= 2)
        return new string(new[] { s[s.Length - 1], s[0] });
    else
        return s;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you take always the **first** and the **last** character of the string then the reversion is irrelevant and you can directly use the index and just swap the otput:

```
var input = "abcdefg";
Console.WriteLine("{1} - {0}", input[0], input[input.Length - 1]);
```

Output is:

```
g - a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string F(string s)
{
     return s.Length >= 2 ? new string(new[] { s.Last(), s.First() }) : s;
}
```