# Convert from VB to C# certificate

Tags: c#, vb.net, certificate

I have this code in visual basic:

```
Dim CERT_SIS As String = "my.cer"
Dim CerNo As String
Dim CerSAT As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate
CerSAT = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(CERT_SIS)
CerNo = StrReverse(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(CerSAT.GetSerialNumber))
```

I want to convert it to C#...

and it gives me error with this code:

```
CerNo = StrReverse(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(CerSAT.GetSerialNumber))
```

how can I do it?

Comment: Use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/228060/1517578. The rest should be a straight conversion..

Comment: Error: System.Text.Encoding.GetString(byte[]) has some invalid arguments

Comment: `.GetSerialNumber()` is a method, and you are missing the '( )'.

Comment: and what about "StrReverse"...

Comment: @SimonWhitehead now the link worked thanks so much guys...how to mark the question resolved?

Comment: Someone will have to post an answer that you can mark to resolve the issue.  My fluency with `VB.NET` is marginal at best so, perhaps Simon can post an answer for you?