# How do I alternate the case in a string?

Tags: c#, case-sensitive

I need to alternate the case in a sentence and I don't know how to.
For example:

```
thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog
```

to

```
GoDyZaLeHtReVoSpMuJxOfNwOrBkCiUqEhT
```

this is my code so far

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a sentence:");
        string text = Console.ReadLine();
        text = text.Replace(" ", "");
        char[] reversed = text.ToCharArray();//String to char
        Array.Reverse(reversed);//Reverses char
        new string(reversed);//Char to string

        Console.WriteLine(reversed);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Please note that there are no spaces for a reason as that's also part of the homework task.

Comment: What have you tried? This is somewhat trivial and you should at least have some code to show before we help you.

Comment: Also, what rationale are you using to change the casing?

Comment: why are you reversing chars ? or did you just copy paste that code from another question?

Comment: @Selman22 reversing is also part of the homework task

Comment: @musiclover - So why isn't your expected output reversed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point to reverse your string. Just upper case your even number indexed characters in your string.

Remember, my culture is `tr-TR` and this [`String.ToUpper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ewdd6aed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method works depends on your current thread culture. In this example, your output can be different than mine.

Here an example in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/);

```
string s = "thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        sb.Append(s[i].ToString().ToUpper());
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append(s[i].ToString());
    }
}
sb.ToString().Dump();
```

Output will be;

```
ThEqUiCkBrOwNfOxJuMpSoVeRtHeLaZyDoG
```

Comment: The alternating worked, thanks. and also, reversing was part of the homework task

Comment: @musiclover Take a look at [Best way to reverse a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

A string is immutable, so, you need to convert it to a char[].

```
char[] characters = text.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i+=2) {
    characters[i] = char.ToUpper(characters[i]);
}
text = new string(characters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution with LINQ can be done in one line like this:

```
string s = "thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog";
string result = new String(s
                            // take each character
                            .ToCharArray()
                            // convert every character at even index to upper
                            .Select ((character, index) => (index % 2) == 0 ? Char.ToUpper(character) : character)
                            // back to array in order to create a string
                            .ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The output is:

```
ThEqUiCkBrOwNfOxJuMpSoVeRtHeLaZyDoG
```

This solution uses the [indexed LINQ Select clause](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) in order to access the current index and the value that is currently projected.

Answer (score 0):

A one liner:

```
new string(myString.Select((c, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? char.ToUpper(c) : c).ToArray())
```

An extension method:

```
 public static string AltCase(this string s)
 {
     return new string(s.Select((c, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? char.ToUpper(c) : c).ToArray());
 }
```