# Why isn't this causing an infinite loop of events?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, textchanged

I have a simple application that reverses any text typed to it in another textbox. The catch is, you can modify either textbox and the changes will be (literally) reflected in the other.

I wrote this code, believing for it to cause problems.

```
private void realText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mirrorText.Text = mirror(realText.Text);
}

private void mirrorText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    realText.Text = mirror(mirrorText.Text);
}

private string mirror(string text)
{
    return new string(text.Reverse().ToArray()).Replace("\n\r", "\r\n");
}
```

I then tried it out, believing that it would cause an infinite loop (`realText` changes `mirrorText`, another event happens, `mirrorText` changes `realText`, etc). However, nothing except the intended behavior happened.

I'm of course happy about this, I could just leave it here. *Or could I?*

I'm quite sure the `TextChanged` event is supposed to be fired whenever `Text` is changed. Is this intended behavior of some error protection in the events, or was I just lucky? Can this code misbehave on another computer, with other build settings, etc? It can be easily fixed:

```
private void realText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (realText.Focused)
    {
        mirrorText.Text = Mirror(realText.Text);
    }
}
```

I'll probably do it anyway to be safe, but is it **required** to check this? (I'm not even going to ask if it's recommended.)

Comment: Im pretty sure TextChanged event is only fired when the text is changed from the UI not from code.

Comment: @Magnus from MSDN: This event is raised if the Text property is changed by either a programmatic modification or user interaction.

Comment: @Magnus, you could use Reflector (I think that was what it was called, right? or the JetBrains one... uh... can't remember the name) to check and see!

Comment: It's possible that setting `Text` to exactly the value already has does not trigger the `TextChanged` event, because it doesn't actually change.

Comment: @Marton, the in-IDE documentation also says `Event raised when the value of the Text property is changed on Control`.

Comment: @Marton I stand corrected.

Comment: @hvd It seems you were right. Please write an answer, so I can accept it. I made `mirror()` so that it changes input, got a stack overflow.

Comment: An interesting comment: "Event is only raised if TextBox is in the visual tree" from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: @Pietu1998 I do not know if it is guaranteed, and if it is the case in all implementations (older versions of .NET Framework, and Mono), so I do not know if you should work around it.

Comment: @hvd I'm going to assume it's not always the case and add my workaround included in the question in my code.

Comment: @Marton: That applies to a WPF (and probably Silverlight / WinRT) TextBox.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Per the comments, and as already answered, the `TextChanged` event is not getting raised when you set the `Text` property to the value it already has.

It's not clear whether this is something you can safely rely upon. It is a sensible optimisation, and I would be very surprised if future versions of .NET Framework drop it, but I cannot speak for older versions, nor for third-party implementations (Mono).

To be absolutely safe, I would *not* use the `Focused` check you put in your question. I would do *exactly* what the `Text` setter does now.

```
private void realText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newMirrorText = Mirror(realText.Text);
    if (mirrorText.Text != newMirrorText)
        mirrorText.Text = newMirrorText;
}
```

This has the same advantage of preventing infinite recursion, but plays more nicely with other code you may put in your form that changes the text as a result of some other event.

Answer (score 22):

The reason it doesn't cause a loop is that it checks whether the `Text` property actually changed, i.e. if the new value does not equal the old value. In your case the `mirror` function happens to reverse itself, which leads to the same text after two passes.

Comment: @Pietu1998 (and @Basic): Thanks for the edits. Had to delay editing it myself, and found it already contained two perfect edits when I came back.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'll give the accept to [user:hvd], as they suggested this first and posted a more thorough answer. I appreciate your answer, though.

Comment: @Pietu1998: No worries :)

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty easy to check.

First, replace both textbox controls with

```
    class T : TextBox
    {
        public override string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                base.Text = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Second, set the breakpoint on setter. Add these expressions to the Watch window:

- Name
- Text
- value

Third, launch the app, copy '123' from somewhere and paste it to the first textbox. Here it goes:

1st break:

- Name:    "mirrorText"
- Text:    ""
- value:   "321"

2nd break:

- Name:    "realText"
- Text:    "123"
- value:   "123"

3rd... whoops, it does not breaks anymore. To detect why we had to go deeper. Look at referencesource: text box setter [does nothing](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBox.cs,464) unusual, but TextBoxBase's one [looks interesting](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,1235):

```
        set {
            if (value != base.Text) { // Gotcha!
                base.Text = value;
                if (IsHandleCreated) {
                    // clear the modified flag
                    SendMessage(NativeMethods.EM_SETMODIFY, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
```

So, as **hvd** already answered, the reason is the textbox does not raise TextChanged if old and new values are the same. I don't think the behavior will change, at least for winforms. But if you want more robust solution, here it is:

```
    private void RunOnce(ref bool flag, Action callback)
    {
        if (!flag)
        {
            try
            {
                flag = true;
                callback();
            }
            finally
            {
                flag = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool inMirror;
    private void realText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RunOnce(ref inMirror, () =>
        {
            mirrorText.Text = mirror(realText.Text);
        });
    }

    private void mirrorText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RunOnce(ref inMirror, () =>
        {
            realText.Text = mirror(mirrorText.Text);
        });
    }

    private string mirror(string text)
    {
        return new string(text.Reverse().ToArray()).Replace("\n\r", "\r\n");
    }
```

P.S. mirror() will fail on surrogate pairs. [Here're](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string#228460) some solutions.

Comment: Thank you for a more in-depth inspection. I'll probably just use the simple TextBox, though. And just by the way, I rewrote mirror() to do something else, that one was just for testing the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

If textbox has a Text, and we try to change it with the same Text, the TextChange event is not raising because new text is same as the previous.
In your code, the realText_TextChanged event reverses the text and changes the mirrorText with it.
The mirrorText_TextChanged event reverses the text and try to change the realText.
The realText has already this text and does not raises the realText_TextChanged event.