# Please help me to check this code for string reverse in C?

Tags: c, string

I'm writing this code to reverse the string, but somehow the last `printf()` seems can not print out the update string. I want to know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char x[] = "abcdefghijklmn";
    int j = sizeof(x);
    int i = 0;
    char t = 'a';
    printf("%s,%i\n", x, j / 2);

    for (; i < j / 2; i++) {
        t = x[i];
        x[i] = x[j - i - 1];
        x[j - i - 1] = t;
        printf("%c,%i,%i\n", x[i], i, j - i - 1);
    }

    printf("%s\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

【LET ME SUMMARIZE】Thank you guys, after reading all your answers, I've rewrite the code, which is quite clear to show the difference between `sizeof()` and `strlen()`, also it was a simpler way to reverse your string. check it and leave your comment if you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void StringReverse(char *s) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = strlen(s) - 1;
        printf("sizeof:%i,strlen:%i\n",sizeof(s),strlen(s));
        for (; i < j + 1; i++)
            printf("%c", s[j - i]);
    }

int main() {
    char x[] = "abcdefghijklmn";
    printf("sizeof:%i,strlen:%i\n",sizeof(x),strlen(x));
    StringReverse(x);

    return 0;
}
```

The result is :

```
sizeof:15,strlen:14
sizeof:4,strlen:14
nmlkjihgfedcba
```

Then check this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void StringReverse(char *s) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = strlen(s) - 1;
        printf("sizeof:%i,strlen:%i\n",sizeof(s),strlen(s));
        for (; i < j + 1; i++)
            printf("%c", s[j - i]);
    }

int main() {
    char x[100];
    puts("Input a tring to reverse:");
    fgets(x,100,stdin);

    printf("sizeof:%i,strlen:%i\n",sizeof(x),strlen(x));
    StringReverse(x);

    return 0;
}
```

And the result is:

```
Input a tring to reverse:
abcdefghijklmn
sizeof:100,strlen:15
sizeof:4,strlen:15

nmlkjihgfedcba
```

It is clear now that `strlen()` alway try to give the real length of the string, but why the first length is 14, the second input way it is 15?

`sizeof()` is defined by the number you put in the char x[] ,always include EOS;

and pointer variable to a string, `sizeof()` always return the pointer length instead of the string length.

【Thanks to @David C. Rankin】Your code reminds me that array variable is always used as a pointer to be passed to the function, so the original string is always **not** preserved no matter you use **common function**(first code below) or **pointer to funtion**(second code below). Correct?

first:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    void StringReverse(char *s) {
                int i = 0;
                int j = strlen(s);
                printf("sizeof:%i,strlen:%i\n",sizeof(s),strlen(s));

                char t = 'a';
                    for (; i < j / 2; i++) {
                        t = s[i];
                        s[i] = s[j - i - 1];
                        s[j - i - 1] = t;
                    }

                printf("%s\n", s);
            }

        int main() {
            char x[]="abcdefghijklmn";

/* if you instead write char *x="abcdefghijklmn"; here 
the compiler will encounter error, because a pointer to 
a 【string literal】 can not be used to modify the string.
*/ 
            printf("sizeof:%i,strlen:%i\n",sizeof(x),strlen(x));
            StringReverse(x);
            printf("\n%s\n", x);  //original string x is not preserved.
            return 0;
        }
```

the result is:

```
sizeof:15,strlen:14
sizeof:4,strlen:14
nmlkjihgfedcba

nmlkjihgfedcba
```

second:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *StringReverse(char *s) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = strlen(s);
    printf("sizeof:%i,strlrn:%i\n", sizeof(s), strlen(s));

    char t = 'a';
    for (; i < j / 2; i++) {
        t = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j - i - 2];
        s[j - i - 2] = t;
    }

    return s;
}

int main() {
    char x[100];
    puts("Input a tring to reverse:");
    fgets(x, 100, stdin);

    printf("sizeof:%i,strlrn:%i\n", sizeof(x), strlen(x));
    StringReverse(x);

    printf("\n%s\n", x);  //original string x is not preserved.

    return 0;
}
```

the result is：

```
Input a tring to reverse:
abcdefghijklmn
sizeof:100,strlrn:15
sizeof:4,strlrn:15

nmlkjihgfedcba
```

So if you want to preserve the original string, you have to use some other way:

...to be continue

Comment: sizeof vs. strlen problem maybe?

Comment: `sizeof(x)` include EOS(`'\0'`)

Comment: You might like to read here http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and then try to debug such issues yourself.

Comment: I don't think it's sizeof problem I didn't use it on pointer variable. May should be j-i-2 instead of j-i-1 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to reverse a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lee, I'm glad you enjoyed the project. You can learn a lot from taking the time to really understand basic pointer, character and memory operations involved in seemingly simple tasks. I enjoyed looking through your final version. Here are a few more for you to digest and compare. See if you can tease out the proper use of each:

**A void version**

(hint: pass pointers to beginning and ending characters of the range of characters to be reversed)

```
/** strreverse - reverse string given by begin and end pointers.
 *  Takes valid string and swaps src & dest each iteration.
 *  The original string is not preserved.
 *  If str is not valid, no action taken.
 */
void strreverse (char *begin, char *end)
{
    char tmp;

    if (!begin || !end) {
        printf ("%s() Error: invalid begin or end\n", __func__);
        return;
    }

    while (end > begin)
    {
        tmp = *end;
        *end-- = *begin;
        *begin++ = tmp;
    }
}
```

**A `char*` version modifying the original**

```
/** strrevstr - reverse string, swaps src & dest each iteration.
 *  Takes valid string and reverses, original is not preserved.
 *  If str is valid, returns pointer to str, NULL otherwise.
 */
char *strrevstr (char *str)
{
    if (!str) {
        printf ("%s() Error: invalid string\n", __func__);
        return NULL;
    }

    char *begin = str;
    char *end = str + strlen (str) - 1;
    char tmp;

    while (end > begin)
    {
        tmp = *end;
        *end-- = *begin;
        *begin++ = tmp;
    }

    return str;
}
```

**A `char*` version that preserves (copies) the original**

```
/** strrevdup - reverse duplicate string, swaps src & dest each iteration.
 *  Takes valid string, duplicates and reverses, original is preserved.
 *  Returns pointer to reversed string on success, NULL otherwise.
 *  Requires string.h, caller is responsible for freeing memory allocated.
 */
char *strrevdup (char* str)
{
    if (!str) {
        printf ("%s() Error: invalid string\n", __func__);
        return NULL;
    }

    char *rstr = strdup (str);
    char *begin = rstr;
    char *end = rstr + strlen (rstr) - 1;
    char tmp;

    while (end > begin){
        tmp=*end;
        *end-- = *begin;
        *begin++ = tmp;
    }

    return rstr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is with the usage of `sizeof()` operator. The way you use

```
int j = sizeof(x);
```

is not correct in this context. What you want here is to make use of `strlen()`  function from `string.h` header file.

*Case 1:*

`sizeof()` operator returns the *size* of the datatype. `x` is an array of `char`s, and when initalized with the string literal `"abcdefghijklmn"`, it takes `15` `char`s. [14 alphabet + 1 terminating null.] to store the value.

Thus, `sizeof(x)` will return `15`.

*Case 2:*

OTOH, `strlen()` does not count the terminating null, so `strlen(x)` will return `14`.

Next, as we know, array index in `C` are `0-based`, that means an array consisting of `n` elements, will have index running from `0` to `n-1`.

So, in case 1, while using the value `j-1`, we're referring to the terminating null, which will be copied and put to the `0`th index, essentially marking the end of the *string*. So,l while printing out the reversed array as a *string*, the very first element, beinh null, marks the end of the *string* and doesn't output anything.

OTOH< in case 2, using the value `j-1`, we're referring to the last *alphanbetic* `char` value present in the array `x` which will be copied to the `0`th index. The copying will continue this way and we'll have a *reversed* string in pace.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line

```
int j = sizeof(x);
```

To

```
int j = sizeof(x)-1;
```

As `sizeof(x)` will return 15 (14 array characters and 1 null character).
where as array index is from 0 to 13.

when `i=0;` and as `j` is 15.

```
x[i] = x[j - i - 1]; //x[0] = x[15-0-1]; i.e x[14] which is NULL.
```

As `x[14]` is null character which is assign to `x[0]`.
So while printing the string it getting null character at first place which is termination of string, That is why it is not giving any output.

I will always prefer to use `strlen` to get length of the string as it will not include null character.
In second thought you can also use

```
int j = strlen(x);  // this will return 14.
```

use "string.h" header file to use this function.

Comment: Using `sizeof` will only work if there is no slack space in the array. For example, with `char x[10]="abc";` it will fail. See answer from @SouravGhosh.

Comment: @WeatherVane, it is better to use `strlen` for these type of conditions. but as OP asked question using `sizeof` without providing any array limit, so i given this answer. I will prefer `strlen` over `sizeof`.

Comment: what do you mean by : Using sizeof will only work if there is no slack space in the array.

Comment: @LeeWilliam, No you are getting it wrong, I said in this question, there is no slack space in array. `sizeof` will work in both cases.

Comment: I understand now but usually I put no number when declare char x[]="sabsdjkaskdnks"; so sizeof will always return the correct size.

Comment: @LeeWilliam, yes you are right and example given by you `x[10]="abc";` , shows in this case `sizeof` will fail to work as required. so i edited my answer and added line to use `strlen` function.

Answer (score 0):

try to print reversed string like that:

```
for (i = 1; i < sizeof(x); i++) 
    printf("%c", x[i]);
```

instead of:

```
 printf("%s\n", x);
```

Answer (score 0):

The last char of the array is '\0',can not reverse it

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char x[] = "abcdefghijklmn";
    int j = sizeof(x);
    int i = 0;
    char t = 'a';
    printf("%s,%i\n", x, j / 2);

    for (; i < j / 2; i++) {
        t = x[i];
        x[i] = x[j - i - 2];
        x[j - i - 2] = t;
        printf("%c,%i,%i\n", x[i], i, j - i - 2);
    }

    printf("%s\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof()` will return the value with `null` terminating byte. It will lead to that run a loop one iteration extra.

So change that into like this,

```
int j=sizeof(x)-1;
```

Or else use the `strlen` function.

Include the header file `#include<string.h>`

```
int j=strlen(x);
```