# How to flip a string?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can i flip a string in `c#` application like for example : "**AMBULANCE**" text that is seen as mirror image.I dont have any idea to where to start with .im using `c#` **forms application**

I have tried for reversing the string ,but is there any possibility to flip a string (like mirror images)?

**Like : `ƎƆИA⅃UᙠMA`**

This is not reversing as in [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string)

Comment: What are you using to draw the text? just a console? window forms, WPF? OpenGL, DirectX ... you can do it but we need to know the technology.

Comment: What are you using to draw the string? WPF, WinForms, Console? OpenGL?

Comment: @utility `string` is just a sequence of byte values like `[45, 23, 48]`. What you are trying to do is changing the way these bytes are displayed somewhere. Without knowing where you display string we cannot help you

Comment: You should create dictionary with normal and flipped characters and use it after reverse.

Comment: @AlexeyNis has the right idea. You can use a site like this to build up a list of flipped characters by typing in the alphabet: http://txtn.us/mirror-words the other option is of course to use an image as others have suggested

Comment: ¿ʎןןɐɔıʇɹǝʌ sɹǝʇɔɐɹɐɥɔ ǝɥʇ buıddıןɟ ʇnoqɐ ʍoɥ

Comment: I don't see any pattern usage (and I think it's normal there is **not** one) between `ƎƆ` characters (which they are `U+018E` and `U+0186` in order) and `CE` which they are `U+0043` and `U+0045`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As well as the approach outlined by Sergey, you can also use [`Graphics.ScaleTransform()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhc2xxtx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to reflect everything about the Y-axis.

For example, create a default Windows Forms application and drop the following `OnPaint()` into it, then run it:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    string text = "This will come out backwards";

    e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(-1, 1);
    float w = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, this.Font).Width;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, this.Font, Brushes.Black, -w, 0);
}
```

Output:

[image: The text reflected about Y]

You can also mess around with `Graphics.RotateTransform()` to rotate the text as well, and use `Graphics.ScaleTransform(1, -1)` to invert it as well as mirror it:

[image]

Comment: Nice approach, I didn't know about ScaleTransform option

Answer (score 4):

You can create bitmap, write string into it and then flip bitmap horizontally with [Image.RotateFlip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rotateflip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height);
var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
g.DrawString("AMBULANCE", font, brush, pictureBox.DisplayRectangle);
bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
pictureBox.Image = bitmap; // display bitmap on your form
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you @Sergey for your time..but rather using images would like to go with strings/texts

Comment: @utility why? That's just an in-memory bitmap (2-dementional array of pixels). With WinForms any string will be finally drawn to GDI drawing surface. It doesn't matter whether it's your control or in-memory bitmap.

Comment: @utility The only way to use just strings would be to use a special reversed font and then reverse the string before displaying it in that font.

Answer (score 1):

Summary:
Winforms use Unicode encoding and you can use "flipped" characters.
For this purpose you should create Dictionary with normal and flipped characters and use it after reverse.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<char, char>
           {
               {'A','A'},
               {'B','ᙠ'},
               {'C','Ɔ'},
               {'D','ᗡ'},
               // etc.
           };
var str = "ABcd";
var mirror = new string(str.ToUpper().Reverse().Select(x=>dict[x]).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to achieving this.

First, the easy part (assuming you are only dealing with Latin-based characters), `string.Reverse()` will reverse the order of the characters. [Otherwise use a technique such as this from an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228060/7122).

The second part has two possible solutions. Either grab yourself a reversed-character font ([free ones exist](http://www.fontspace.com/wa2ise/backwards)) and display the reversed string using that. Or, use a site such as http://txtn.us/mirror-words to build up a list of characters that look like reversed ones and then set up a dictionary to map between them, eg

```
var Dictionary<char, char> = new Dictionary<char, char>
{
    ...
    { 'e', 'ɘ' },
    ...
};
```

Then you can do a character-by-character replacement and display that string. Obviously that will only work if your chosen font has those characters in it.