# cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<char>' to 'string'

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, generics

I try to Reverse my string but I get to following error

```
string str = word.Reverse();
```

error:

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'string'

anyone know what should I need to do ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/228060/772086

Comment: @Mike Why? If word is a string, Reverse returns an IEnumerable char and you get that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should join characters together to make new string.

```
string str = string.Join(string.Empty, word.Reverse());
```

Answer (score 11):

You should build a new string.

```
string str = new string(word.Reverse().ToArray());
```

Calling `ToArray()` on an `IEnumerable<T>` will convert it to `T[]`.

`string` has a constructor which get array of character and constructs a string.