# Writing a base conversion tool and having trouble with hexadecimal

Tags: c#, hex

My current assignment is to write a converter to different systems.
Converting to binary was no problem, but I am having some troubles with hexadecimal. Here is my code:

```
    public string[] ConvertInput(int pInput, int pBase)
    {
        List<string> Output = new List<string>();
        int Tmp = pInput;
        int TmpBin;

        for (int i = 0; Tmp > 0; i++)
        {
            TmpBin = Tmp % pBase;
            Tmp = Tmp / pBase;
            if (TmpBin >= 10)
            {
                char c = (char)TmpBin;
                Output.Add(c.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                Output.Add(TmpBin.ToString()); 
            }
        }

        string[] OutArray = Output.ToArray();

        Array.Reverse(OutArray);

        return OutArray;
    }
```

So if I try to convert the number `15555` to hexadecimal, it should give `3cc3` back, but what it does is return `3\f\f3`.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You're casting binary values to char - you aren't converting the binary values to characters in the range 'A' to 'F' correctly.

Comment: BTW, you can get rid of the array of strings approach and just do it all in one string.  You'll need a Reverse of string method, though.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/228060/49251.  So you can do it with output declard `string Output = ""`.  Then you add to it via `Output += c.ToString();`, etc.  Then referse the string and have the method return a string.

Comment: @Raphnika: I see you edited your question to re-include the "thanks" at the end -- the general consensus around here is to omit any kind of "thanks" from your posts. Think of questions and answers here as technical writing -- while it may seem harsh, there's just no point. Thank your answerer(s) by accepting or upvoting when appropriate.

Comment: @Cory Alright... changed it back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
if (TmpBin >= 10)
{
    char c = (char)TmpBin;
    Output.Add(c.ToString());
}
```

Do this:

```
if (TmpBin >= 10)
{
    char c = (char)('A' + (TmpBin - 10));
    Output.Add(c.ToString());
}
```

In your version, you are casting the decimal values 10, 11, 12 etc directly to characters, and (for example) the character with code 10 is line feed, not `'A'`.

Comment: Allright! Got it. Thank you very much for your help and have a nice day!

Comment: I know this was an assignment, but in an actual .NET production application, you could and should replace your entire method with `15555.ToString("X");`. You wouldn't want to recreate the wheel, though your professor probably wants to you to do it the hard way.

Comment: @Cory yeah... he wants us to understand how everything works.