# How to convert the text direction to normal

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, devexpress

I am reading an arabic localized pdf document in memory using c# and after reading the text i am getting it like this

```
٩٠/٤٠/٧٣٤١ ٩١/١٠/٦١٠٢
```

but the correct direction of this text in pdf is `٢٠١٦/٠١/١٩ ١٤٣٧/٠٤/٠٩`

Can somebody please guide how can change this text direction to proper direction as it is appearing in pdf.

**Edit**

This is the function i am using. I am using Devexpress Document server, I am skipping upto line 36 as I do not need the data before line 36.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (var documentStream = new FileStream(@"D:\Data\Projects\DotNet\ElectricBillReader\electricbill.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (PdfDocumentProcessor documentProcessor = new PdfDocumentProcessor())
                {
                    documentProcessor.LoadDocument(documentStream);

                    using (var sr = new StringReader(documentProcessor.Text))
                    {
                        var counter = 0;
                        string line = string.Empty;
                        do
                        {
                            line = sr.ReadLine();
                            if (counter > 36)
                            {
                                if (line != null)
                                {

                                }
                            }
                            counter++;
                        } while (line!=null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: "Being in the correct order" is a property of the string as a whole, not of the individual characters. When displayed with capable software, the string *will* appear in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna need a library that implements the [Unicode bidirectional algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/), i'm not aware of any libraries that does this for .NET but there's an effort to port [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) to .NET [here](https://github.com/sillsdev/icu-dotnet)

Also, check this out: https://sourceforge.net/projects/nbidi/

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about just reversing the string?

```
public static string Reverse( string s )
{
    char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse( charArray );
    return new string( charArray );
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string)