# How to "invert" the value of a string?

Tags: c#, string

In C# want to do something like this:

```
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
strBuilder.append("123");
```

And then some code

```
//Outputs 321 (works for any text value)
```

Comment: new StringBuilder("123").reverse().toString()

Comment: what is your programming language? And did you have a look at its documentation?

Comment: Please clarify whether this is java or C#

Answer (score 0):

**In C#**

```
public string Reverse(string s) {
    return new string(Array.Reverse(s.ToCharArray()));
}
```

From above 3.5 Framework:

```
public string Reverse(string s) {
    return new string(s.Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

See [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228060/5352399).

Comment: If the first code sample was borrowed from somewhere it would be fair if you gave credits to the original author.

Comment: @zerkms i agree but frankly speaking reversing a String in java or C# is not a difficult thing. i knew that previously.

Comment: Well, if you copy-paste someone's code, even if it's trivial - it's still not your solution.