# C# : Find the largest palindromic number made from product of 3-digit numbers

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program to find the largest palindromic number made from product of 3-digit numbers. Firstly,i Create a method which has ability to check if it is a palindromic number. Here is my code :

```
static int check(string input_number)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input_number.Length/2; i++)
        if (input_number[i] != input_number[input_number.Length - i])
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

After that, it's my main code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 999; j++)
        {
            k = i * j;
            if (check(k.ToString()) == 1)
                Console.Write(k + "      ");
        }
}
```

But when it has a problem that the length of `input_number` is zero. So my code doesn't run right way. What can I do to solve the length of `input_number`?

Comment: Start at `i=100` and `j=100`. "3 digit numbers" start at `100`, not at `0`.

Comment: in the **check** method, try initializing the **for** index from 1, so `for (int i = 1; i < input_number.Length / 2; i++)`

Comment: Oh, and _include_ `999`, it has 3 digits, too :)

Comment: @Innat3 why that? strings are indexed zero-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use method below. Because you are trying to find the largest number you start from 999 and head backwards, do multiplication and check if its palindrome.

```
private void FindProduct()
{
 var numbers = new List<int>();
 for (int i = 999; i > 99; i--)
 {
    for (int j = 999; j > 99; j--)
    {
        var product = i * j;
        var productString = product.ToString();
        var reversed = product.Reverse();
        if (product == reversed)
        {
               numbers.Add(product);
        }
     }
   }
   Console.WriteLine(numbers.Max());
}
```

Comment: [`Reverse()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228060/1997232) seems more expensive than inner loop (as OP's `check()` method). And you get results sorted from highest number (may be unwanted effect).

Comment: returning first number is wrong, It is possible to find a greater number when you continue loop. For example 913 x 913 greater than 995 x 583 which comes first in the loop.

Comment: Added change, products are added to list and then list maximum is written to output.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few bugs in your code:

#### 1. 3-digit-numbers range from `100` to `999`, not from `0` to `998` as your loops currently do.

So your `Main` method should look like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++)
        for (int j = 100; j <= 999; j++)
        {
            k = i * j;
            if (check(k.ToString()) == 1)
                Console.Write(k + "      ");
        }
}
```

Now all pairs of three digit numbers are checked. But to improve performance you can let `j` start at `i`, because you already checked e.g. `213 * 416` and don't need to check `416 * 213` anymore:

```
for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++)
    for (int j = i; j <= 999; j++) // start at i
```

And since you want to find the largest, you may want to start at the other end:

```
for (int i = 999; i >= 100; i--)
    for (int j = 999; j >= 100; j--)
```

But that still *does not guarantee that the first result will be the largest*. You need to collect the result and sort them. Here is my LINQ suggestion for your `Main`:

```
var results = from i in Enumerable.Range(100, 900)
                    from j in Enumerable.Range(i, 1000-i)
                    let k = i * j
                    where (check(k.ToString() == 1)
                    orderby k descending
                    select new {i, j, k};
var highestResult = results.FirstOrDefault();

if (highestResult == null)
    Console.WriteLine("There are no palindromes!");
else
    Console.WriteLine($"The highest palindrome is {highestResult.i} * {highestResult.j} = {highestResult.k}");
```

#### 2. Your palindrome-check is broken

You compare the character at index `i` to `input_number[input_number.Length - i]`, which will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` for `i = 0`. Strings are zero-based index, so index of the last character is `Length-1`. So change the line to

```
if (input_number[i] != input_number[input_number.Length - i - 1])
```

Finally, I suggest to make the `check` method of return type `bool` instead of `int`:

```
static bool check(string input_number)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input_number.Length/2; i++)
        if (input_number[i] != input_number[input_number.Length - i - 1])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

This seems more natural to me.

Comment: I'd still reverse the order though if then end goal is to just find the highest

Comment: @ganders Starting at `999` does not guarantee to find the largest _palindrome_ at first. It's still necessary to collect the results and find the largest. I added that to my answer.

Comment: @ganders e.g.  191*275 = 52525, but 225*233 = 52425.

Comment: @ganders ok, that example does not prove anything :) but I still can't see an easy proof that the highest palindrome necessarily has the highest factor on one side, though it seems to be the case for three digit numbers.