# Error in type converting

Tags: c#

firstly i would like to say sorry because of very easy question for you guys , as i am beginner , i am trying to write a program to take input in a string and reverse it in new string , so i can compare if both strings are same than it is palindrome..

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Assg2_question1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string word, reverse ="";
                Console.WriteLine("type any word to check if it palindrome or not");
                word =  Console.ReadLine();
                int lengthOfWord, i;
                lengthOfWord = word.Length;
                for(i=lengthOfWord ; i>=1 ; i-- )
                {
                    reverse = word[lengthOfWord];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

i have two string word and  reverse , when i try to reverse the string it shows error on  **reverse = word[lengthOfWord];** can not implicitly convert type char to string, why is that ? because i never use char in my program

Comment: `reverse` is a string variable while `word[lengthOfword]` returns a character at a specific index in the word string. So here conversion from char to string is not possible. that's what the error is about.

Comment: You use char. Your word[lengthOfWord] returns single character which is a char. To see it better you can do `char letter = word[lengthOfWord]; reverse = letter.ToString()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to reverse a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string)

Comment: string word = string.Empty; 
            string reverse = string.Empty;
            Console.WriteLine("type any word to check if it palindrome or not");
            word = Console.ReadLine();
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (var i = word.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var ch = word[i];
                sb.Append(word[i]);
            }
            reverse = sb.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(word);
            Console.WriteLine(reverse);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx). Also your array bounds checking was messed up here. Array index starts from `0` and `word.Length - 1` is the last index:

```
string word , reverse = "";
Console.WriteLine("type any word to check if it palindrome or not");
word = Console.ReadLine();
int lengthOfWord, j;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
lengthOfWord = word.Length - 1;
for (j = lengthOfWord; j >= 0; j--)
{
    sb.Append(word[j]);
}
reverse = sb.ToString();
```

You got the error because `word[j]` is a char and not a string. Also string is immutable better use StringBuilder.

Comment: May it would be worth pointing out that OP is not using the correct index `i` to index the chars in `word`.

Comment: Thanks man ,  i learned what i did not know  before " stringbuilder

Answer (score 1):

You can also reverse a string using LINQ:

```
var reverse = new string(word.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());
```

If a for loop is your thing then this will work:

```
var reverse = "";
for (int i = word.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    reverse += word[i];
}
```

Note the difference between your code :
 `reverse = word[lengthOfWord]` versus `reverse += word[i]`
The former assigns each time the last character, while the latter adds each seperate character to the string.

But in that case, using a stringbuilder is more efficient:

```
var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
for (int i = word.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    sb.Append(word[i]);
}
var reverse = sb.ToString();
```

That's because String is an immutable object. So whenever the content of a string is modified, it will actually allocate a new string in memory. Not very efficient when that's done a lot, like in a loop.
But by using StringBuilder the content of the object can be changed without allocating new memory each iteration.

Comment: why we are doing -1 in total length ?

Comment: oh i got it , the index is start from 0 not from 1  ,

Comment: @faizan Indeed.  The legacy of C lives on.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable word is a `String`. And a `String` is a `Char` array. Because it's an array you can acces it via [index] and that's what you are doing. So when you use `word[lengthOfWord]` you are getting a `Char`. And a `Char` can not be implicitily converted as a `String`.

But when you want to reserve a `String` your logic isn't correct at all.

Comment: reverse = reverse + word[lengthOfWord];

Comment: i edited this after a dry run to hold the previous character , but now it shows error Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: "So when you use `word[lengthOfWord]`" not really doing so results in an out of bound exception. May it would be worth pointing out that OP is not using the correct index `i`.

Comment: @MongZhu That's why I wrote my last sentence. But I thought it would be helpfull for him to know why his code won't complie in the first way so that the could try the next steps on his own.

Comment: if you ask me that you tried to add to 3 and 5 but you get the result of -2, and I answer this with your last sentence. Will you know how to correct your calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Use string builder:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string word = string.Empty; 
        string reverse = string.Empty;
        Console.WriteLine("type any word to check if it palindrome or not");
        word = Console.ReadLine();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = word.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var ch = word[i];
            sb.Append(word[i]);
        }
        reverse = sb.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(word);
        Console.WriteLine(reverse);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```