# How to read character by character right to left?

Tags: c#, string

I hope and you can help me please, I have a label that shows a value in binary.

Example: `"1000010101"`, this data, I'm reading it with an inverted for. That is, starting *from right to left*, the binary number is dynamic, so it will not always be the same.

Until now this is my idea, but it does not give me any value

```
for (int i = lbl_conversion.Text.Length; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (st[i] == 1)
        {
            MessageBox("1");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox("0");
        }

    }
```

What I would like is to read character by character from left to right and know if it is `"1"` or `"0"` and then make a comparison, could someone support me to get that result?

Thank you.

Comment: `int i = lbl_conversion.Text.Length - 1;` please, note `-1`; `i >= 0`

Comment: You should be getting an exception, which should be providing you a big clue about what you're doing wrong here.

Comment: Even if you do get this working, I'm not sure how 10 separate message boxes are useful. What are you actually trying to do with this?

Comment: See also [C# read string from back to end](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43122807/215552)

Comment: "and then make a comparison" comparing to what...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `string`s are *zero based*, correct `for` loop will be

```
   // Note "- 1" and ">=" 
   for (int i = lbl_conversion.Text.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
       if (st[i] == '1') //DONE: comparing with character, not integer
       {
           MessageBox("1");
       }
       else
       {
           MessageBox("0");
       }
```

Or you can just `Reverse` the string (with a help of *Linq*):

```
   // Let's read each character in reversed order
   foreach (char c in lbl_conversion.Text.Reverse())
       MessageBox(c.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

just one more (similar to prev posted)

```
string s="10111011";
s.Reverse().ToList().ForEach(ch=>Console.WriteLine(ch=='1'?"A":"0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need read the string to right to left, typically you know the number of character to have to read.

I have this function.

```
 private string GetValue(string strValor, int lenght)
    {
        if (strValor.Length > lenght)
            return strValor.Substring(strValor.Length - lenght, lenght);
        return strValor;
    }
```

- strValor: String to read.
- lenght: Number of character to read.

Example: GetValue("R6C5736423792", 10); return "5736423792"