# Why does this code not reverse the name given as a value of a variable?

Tags: c#

```
  string myName = "Angel Hadzhiev";
        char[] CharName = myName.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(CharName);
        foreach (char name in myName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

The problem is that the given name(Angel Hadzhiev) is not reversed when I run the Console Application. The output is this - http://prntscr.com/fvbis1

Comment: You can join an array of characters back into a string with the String constructor: `string newString = new String(CharName);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You reverse the characters in `CharName`, but you write to the Console the characters in `myName` (which isn't reversed, and contains the original order). Your loop should have looked like this:

```
    foreach (char name in CharName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It was successful but could you tell my why it is displayed vertically but not horizontally ?

Comment: Because you are using `WriteLine`, which appends new line character(s) to the output of each character. If you used `Write`, it should out put horizontally, as that will output only the characters, without adding the line breaks.

Comment: I got it. Thank you a lot.

Comment: You should mention that `Array.Reverse` [does not reverse strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15111719/22437).

Comment: @DourHighArch - if you're talking about the special case considered by the second answer to that question, then yes, the OP's approach will have problems with some potential strings.

Answer (score 0):

You made a simple mistake that in foeach loop instead of reversed array you are taking old array.

[Please check this link for example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qrTkAG)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myName = "Angel Hadzhiev";
        char[] CharName = myName.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(CharName);
        foreach (char name in CharName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
    }
```