# Reversing a string with constrained requirements

Tags: c#, string, reverse

I just started learning C# and I need some help. I have to reverse a string and check for palindrome using ONLY `if`, `else`, `switch`, `s.Length`, `s.Substring` and `s[]`:

```
    static string MyReverseString(string s)
    {
        int len = s.Length;
        string NewS= "";
        if (len != 0)
        {
            NewS = NewS + s[len];

            return MyReverseString(s.Substring(0, (len - 1)));
        }
        else
        {
            return NewS;

        }
    }
```

and I get

> "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: LINQ: `Reverse()` method.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the post, I can not use other than if, else, Switch, s.Length, s.Substring and s[].

Comment: Whats wring with looping backwards thru the string to assign the chars to a new string?

Comment: @Stijn I already tried " int len = s.Length - 1 ; " and "if(len > 0) " and still didn't work. Thank you for your comment but i can search by myself.

Comment: I suggest you take your time and properly read the duplicate. Then you'll understand why your code doesn't work, and why your other attempt with `- 1` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general idea is correct, but you are not quite there.

When using recursion, code first the case where recursion isn't needed. When reversing a string, what is the trivial case? Well, when the string is empty or is only one character long. Ok, lets do that:

```
public static string Reverse(string s)
{
    if (s.Length <= 1)
        return s;

    //do something else
}
```

Ok, now, if `s` isn't empty, how do we reverse recursively? Well, let's think about what should be returned in the current step. Obviously, if we want to reverse `s`, whatever we return, we know that the first letter needs to be the last letter of `s`. Ok, lets do that and see where it takes us:

```
public static string Reverse(string s)
{
    if (s.Length <= 1)
        return s;

    return s[s.Length - 1] + //something
}
```

And what is that *something*? Well it has to be the reverse of `s` without the last letter, we already took care of that one, remember? But... oh wait! I know how to reverse a string already, don't I? `Reverse(s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1)` (isn't recursion magical?)

Et violá:

```
public static string Reverse(string s)
{
    if (s.Length <= 1)
        return s;

    return s[s.Length - 1] + Reverse(s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1));
}
```

You didn't even need `switch` and `else`.

Comment: You are the best! Thank you! Cheers

Comment: Trivial case condition can be slightly optimised to `s.Length <= 1` (single-character string does not need to be reversed) and `Reverse(` is missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: @Ňuf true! Will update.

Answer (score 0):

Here, s[len] is throwing an IndexOutOfRange exception. Lets say - If you have string s = "abc" then index start from 0. So s[2] would be "c" and length of string is 3. So, if you try to get s[len] which is s[3], it will throw an exception.

Check it out - 
[Best way to reverse a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

To reverse the string you cut it in half, swap the halves and reverse them recursively in this manner until they are the size of 1 or 0 characters.

To check for palindrome you check if the first and the last character are the same. If that is not true, the string is definitely not a palindrome. If true, then check if the smaller part of the original string (besides the first and the last character) is a palindrome recursively in the same way.

```
    static string Reverse(string s)
    {
        if (s.Length >= 2)
            return Reverse(s.Substring(s.Length / 2)) + Reverse(s.Substring(0, s.Length / 2));
        else
            return s;
    }

    static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
    {
        if (s.Length <= 1)
            return true;

        if (s[0] == s[s.Length - 1] && IsPalindrome(s.Substring(1, s.Length-2)))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static string MyReverseString(string s)
{
    return MyReverseString(s, s.Length - 1);
}

private static string MyReverseString(string s, int index)
{
    if (index > 0)
    {
        return s[index] + MyReverseString(s, index - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return s[index].ToString();
    }
}
```

This avoids using `.Substring` (which improves efficiency slightly).

If you want to find a palindrome and you don't care about reversing the string, then try this:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
{
    return IsPalindrome(s, 0, s.Length - 1);
}

private static bool IsPalindrome(string s, int start, int finish)
{
    if (finish - start <= 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (s[start] != s[finish])
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return IsPalindrome(s, start + 1, finish - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

This final method can be shortened to:

```
private static bool IsPalindrome(string s, int start, int finish)
{
    return (finish - start <= 0) || (s[start] == s[finish]) && IsPalindrome(s, start + 1, finish - 1);
}
```