# Recursive reversing string C#

Tags: c#, recursion

I don't know how I don't want a direct answer I want to know how can I.
Many thanks in advance.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          Console.WriteLine("Enter a word or sentence to be reversed: ");
          string str = Console.ReadLine();
          Console.WriteLine("**********");
          Console.WriteLine("Your input is: ");
          Console.WriteLine(str);
          Console.ReadLine();//to give a little bit space between the outputs
          Console.WriteLine("************");
          Console.WriteLine("And it will be reversed as : ");
          //call the Recursive Function in the class Recursive
          str = Recursive.Recursive_Func(str);
          Console.WriteLine(str);
          Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

We use Substring to print from the n-1 index in the string 
and end it with the first index in the string which is [0].

```
class Recursive
{
    public static string Recursive_Func(string str)
    {
        if (str.Length <= 1) //the program base case
        {
            return str;
        }
        else
        {
            return Recursive_Func(str.Substring(1)) + str[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually one can surmise the question is "How can I fix my broken program?" As far as I can tell here, the program is correct. It reverses a string using recursion. What is your actual question? How can you *what*?

Comment: See this: [Best way to reverse a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this solution is simpler and easier to understand than the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47507200/4298200).

```
 public static string MyReverse(string s)
 {
     if (s.Length == 1)
     {
         return s;
     }
     var firstLetter = s[0];
     return MyReverse(s.Substring(1)) + firstLetter;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is naïve and slow but it is recursive, and it works. The below implementation converts the string into a char array, uses a recursive helper method to reverse the chars in-place, and converts the reversed array back into a string:

```
class Recursive
{
    public static string StrRev(string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return s;
        var a = s.ToCharArray();
        return new string(CharArrRev(a, 0, a.Length - 1));
    }

    private static char[] CharArrRev(char[] a, int i, int j)
    {
        if (i >= j) return a;
        var c = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = c;
        return CharArrRev(a, i + 1, j - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  public static string recursive(string str)
        {
            if (str.Length == 0)
            {
                return "";
            }
            return str[str.Length - 1] + recursive(str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1));

        }
```

Comment: Add an explaination. It is clear to me what you are doing, but i doubt it is to everyone..