# problems with for loop string

Tags: c#, for-loop

I'm new to programming in c# and I'm trying to figure out how I could
potentially reverse all words except words containing `e` in a string.

my current code will detect words containing `e`, and just writes them down in another textbox:

```
string text = txbInput.Text;
            var words = text.Split(' ');
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                if (words[i].Contains('e'))
                {
                   txbOutput.Text += words[i];
                }
```

Current:

Input: chicken crossing the road

Output: chickenthe

.

Expected outcome:

Input: chicken crossing the road

Output chicken gnissorc the daor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To reverse a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/).

Comment: I'm not trying to make my whole string reversed.

Comment: @DennisTanahatoe you're not, but that question shows how you can do it with a string, so just pass to the method there the strings that do not have an `e` in it?!?!

Comment: Write an `else` case that reverses the word..?

Comment: The logic behind combing those 2 things is the struggle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outputs:** chicken gnissorc the daor

```
using System;


namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = "chicken crossing the road";

            foreach (var item in input.Split(' '))
            {
                if (item.Contains('e'))
                {
                    Console.Write(item + ' ');
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(Reverse(item) + ' ');
                }
            }
        }

        public static string Reverse(string s)
        {
            char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(charArray);
            return new string(charArray);
        }
    }
}
enter code here
```

**EDIT**

```
 foreach (var item in input.Split(' '))
    {
        if (item.Contains('e'))
        {
            txbOutput.Text = txbOutput.Text+ item + ' ';
        }
        else
        {
            txbOutput.Text= txbOutput.Text+ Reverse(item) + ' ';
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Array.Reverse(s.ToCharArray())` [does not reverse strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/).

Comment: The question starts out with "I am new to programming..". I think it is important to work with simple and understandable answers to introduce core concepts.

Comment: What could I potentially add, in order to ignore the special characters?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply split the word on the space character, then, for each word, select either the word itself, or the word reversed (depending on whether or not it contains the 'e' character), and then join them back together again with the space character:

```
txbOutput.Text = string.Join(" ", txbInput.Text.Split(' ')
    .Select(word => word.Contains("e") ? string.Concat(word.Reverse()) : word));
```

Comment: Superb. Neat & elegant!

Comment: [If anyone is curious about the ?: operator (ternary)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following code -

```
string.Join(” “,
      str.Split(‘ ‘)
         .Select(x => new String(x.Reverse().ToArray()))
         .ToArray());
```

Copied from - https://www.declarecode.com/code-solutions/csharp/caprogramtoreverseeachwordinthegivenstring

Comment: Are you affiliated with the Declare Code blog?

Comment: @JeremyCaney no why?