# How to find the index of an element in an array inside a lambda expression in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, indexing, lambda

I want to create a function that flips a string's order

example: `"hi" => "ih"`

here is the code I have come out with so far:

```cs
public static string Flip(this string Str)
{
  char[] chararray = Str.ToCharArray();
  string output = "";
  chararray. //i dont know what methoud should be used to execute action 
  return output; 
}
```

the thing is, i want to know within the lambda expression what is the index of the object that is currently selected ex:`x` in `(x => x )` `indexOf` is not an option as there can be more then one char from the same type

how can I know the index?

edit:
I don't want to know how to reverse a string, I want to know how to find an index of an object in lambda expression

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string

Comment: @fubo read edit

Comment: I just wanted to say that there are better approaches than `indexOf` to flip a string

Comment: You can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) overload of `Select` method. So you can write `chararray.Select((ch, index) => ...`

Comment: Depending on the linq method you can enter a predicate of the format `Func<TSource,Int32,Boolean>` where the `Int32` is the index. As example: `test.Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0)`

Comment: @fubo ok cool I thought you want to mark as duplicate

Comment: Obligatory post by Tony, I mean Jon Skeet https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/

Comment: @CodeCaster duplicate has nothing to do with my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Select` and `Where` extension methods of LINQ, you have an overload that takes two parameters in the lambda, the first is the element, the second is the index.

so in your case if you have a `char` array:

```
var reversedArray = charArray
         .Select((c, i) => new { Element = c, Index = i })
         .OrderByDescending(arg => arg.Index)
         .Select(arg => arg.Element)
         .ToArray();
```

*This is just to demonstrate how to get the index in LINQ extesions methods.
As the question states this is not about how to reverse a string.*