# Reverse a string using c#

Tags: c#

To reverse a string we convert it into an array of characters, then we use a `for` loop to print the reversed string. But in the below program we are getting characters from the string without converting it into characters. I am really confused how it has happened. Variable `str` is string then why `str[i]` is returning a character?

```
public static void Main() {
  string str = "hello mr singh";
  string temp ="";

  for (int i = str.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    temp += str[i];
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Reverse string:" + temp);
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: and what returns `this[int index]` property of string class?

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs line 717 and following. That's why it's a char :)

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'm not sure this question is a duplicate of that you've linked. It's actually nothing to do with reversing strings

Comment: @ChotaVlog *variable str is string then why str[i] is returning a character?* because string has an indexer property `this[int index]` that returns the character at the given index. If I want to know what the 4th character of "Hello World" is, it's perfectly valid C# to say `char c = "Hello World"[3];` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.chars?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Linq solution: `string reversed = string.Concat(str.Reverse());`

Comment: Using `temp += nextCharacter` to build a string is horribly inefficient, since that will copy the string-so-far every time you add a new character. Using StringBuilder is one of several more efficient ways to gradually build a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string str = "hello mr singh";
char[] arr = str.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(arr);
_revArray = string(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

`str` is a string and you can reach each caractere of it using `str[i]`, so to reverse the string the `for` loop begins from the last caractere `int i = str.Length - 1` and store the results in a new string `temp`.

for example if you want to reverse the string `"hello"`, the string length is `5` so the lopp will start from 4 so we will have:

```
str[4] = 'o', str[3] = 'l', str[2] = 'l', str[1] = 'e', str[0] = 'h'
```

finally store the results in the variable `temp`:

```
temp = str[4] + str[3]  + str[2] + str[1] + str[0];
```

so the resulted string is the concatenation of the caracters.

If you want a more efficient way to reverse a string check the answers for this question:
[Best way to reverse a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string?noredirect=1&lq=1)