# C# -> string.Reverse(); - do not work in # using System.Linq;

Tags: c#

This program is not working as expected and I'm not sure why. The error is `CS0266 " 
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<char>' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

BUT,
it should work properly under using System.Linq;

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
namespace centuryyearsminutes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string aa = "Hello World!";
            string bb = aa.Reverse();
            Console.WriteLine(bb);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Linq's Reverse treats a string as an array of characters, and returns a collection of characters, not a string.

Comment: The compiler says you a) The return value of String.Reverse() is not a string, but a `IEnumerable<char>` (a special use case of the array). b) It can not find any implicit conversions between `IEnumerable<char>` and `string`

Comment: Note though that reversing a string character by character will produce the wrong result in lots of cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to reverse a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string)

Answer (score 9):

aa.Reverse() returns just an `Enumerable<char>`

try:

```
string bb = new string(aa.Reverse().ToArray());
```

Although this is probably the best way to do it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15111719/11808788

Answer (score 8):

`.Reverse()` is expecting a collection of characters ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse?view=netframework-4.8)), not a string. If you do:

```
string aa = "Hello World!";

var result = aa.ToCharArray().Reverse();

Console.WriteLine(new string(result.ToArray()));
```

The output is `!dlroW olleH`.

This should work as expected.

Comment: If you'd like to point out something wrong with an answer, feel free to comment and let me know how I can improve -- downvoting without any explanation doesn't help me understand much here :(

Comment: There's no need for ToCharArray (that creates a new unnecessary array), and there's no String ctor which takes an IEnumerable. The downvote is probably because your code won't compile (though it's not mine)

Comment: I missed a `.ToArray()` cast on the `new string()` call. The code compiles and produces a reversed string.

Comment: It does now. It's always worth testing the code you post. The ToCharArray is still unnecessary though.