# Implementation for a method that, with a given string, generates all its possible partitions that are a palindrome, using Linq methods

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, palindrome

I don't even know where to start on this one, as in what methods from *Linq* to use, but i have an example.

If the string would be `"xxyxxz"`, this would be the output (though not necessarily in this order):

```
x x y x x z xx xx xyx xxyxx
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: If string is not very long, you can test every substring (bruteforce) for being palindrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If string is not very long, you can try *brute force*: enumerate all substrings and filter out palindromes. Let's implement pure *Linq* for this:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  string source = "xxyxxz";

  var result = Enumerable
    .Range(1, source.Length)                 // all substrings' lengths
    .SelectMany(length => Enumerable         // all substrings 
       .Range(0, source.Length - length + 1)
       .Select(i => source.Substring(i, length)))
    .Where(item => item.SequenceEqual(item.Reverse())) // Linq to test for palindrome
    .ToArray(); // Let's have an array of required substrings

  // Let's have a look at the result:
  Console.Write(string.Join(" ", result));
```

Outcome:

```
  x x y x x z xx xx xyx xxyxx
```

Comment: And if it is longer, what could i do in a more optimized way?

Comment: @pink_totoro: for *enumerating* substrings in the *worst case* (`"aaaa...a"` - all characters are equal) you'll have a huge answer: `n * (n + 1) / 2` substrings to output; *counting* such substrings (int the example above the answer is `10`) is easier problem https://leetcode.com/problems/palindromic-substrings/

Comment: Assuming there are no [grapheme cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15111719/1336590) shenanigans in the mix.

Comment: @Corak: yes; the first issue is case; moreover unicode strings are complex stuff (same letters can be represent in different ways). Often such (academic) problems assume that string is all small English characters