# Why Console.WriteLine outputs text without a format string and the type name when using a format string?

Tags: c#

I using the codes below to print out the reverse name of a user input but I couldn't understand why the `Console.WriteLine` call prints out "Your reverse name is: System.Char[]"? If I just type `Console.WriteLine(reverseName)`, it print out the reverse name correctly. What is different in this code? Couldn't understand why the usage a placeholder would give different output? Isn't it refer to the same information in `reverseName`?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var name = "Alice";
    char[] reverseName = new char[name.Length];
    for (var i = name.Length - 1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        reverseName[i] = name[name.Length - 1 - i];
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine(reverseName); // "ecilA"
    Console.WriteLine("Your reverse name is: {0} ", reverseName); 
       // "Your reverse name is: System.Char[]"
}
```

Comment: Its because you cant print non-standard types. Char[] will have to be printed as a string so you need to convert that first to a string, `string.Concatenate(Reversenames)` would join the characters and create the string for you.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(char[])` and `Console.WriteLine(string, params object[] args)` are two different methods.

Comment: Do you see `Your reverse name is: is:system.char[]`? That's because the default `ToString` method prints out the name of the type. You need to convert your char array to a string. One way is to change the second argument to `WriteLine` to `new String(Reversenames)`

Comment: Consider rewording your posts _title_ to be more informative.  This will help current and future readers via search engines

Comment: Thanks for solving my confusion, was learning from online video but never aware it is 2 different method so output 2 different result.

Comment: Also, please change this part of your question `at the console writeline it print out your name is:system.char[]?` to something like `the Console.WriteLine call prints out "Your reverse name is: System.Char[]"` As it's written it's very hard to follow (in a large part because what it says is wrong)

Comment: About reverse string you can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both cases you are actually calling different methods. See [Member Overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/member-overloading)

When you call `Console.WriteLine(Reversenames)` you execute method [WriteLine(Char[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-5.0#System_Console_WriteLine_System_Char___), which will convert char array into string.

When you call `Console.WriteLine("some text", Reversenames)` you execute method [WriteLine(String, Object[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-5.0#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object___), which will call `.ToString()` on every object given after the placeholder. `new char[] {}.ToString()` returns exactly what you see "system.char[]"