# I am trying to find if string s1 is palindrome , reverse the string and save it in s2, now s1==s2 , here I am never getting true

Tags: c#, .net

See my code below:

```
string s1 = "madam";
string s2 = string.Empty;

int length = s1.Length - 1;
for (int i = length; i >= 0; i--)
{
   s2 += s1[i];
}
if (s1 == s2)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Palindrome");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Not Palindrome");
}
```

Comment: You can use `s2 = s1.Reverse();` instead of the for loop

Comment: *here I am never getting true* - what do you mean? that s1 is never equal to s2? Works fine for me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/h4bVcR

Comment: Did you load your string by code or user input?

Comment: Your code works fine for word palindromes, but sentence-length palindromes ignore capitalization, punctuation, and word boundaries. It wouldn't work for "Madam, I'm Adam".

Comment: @StefanoCavion by code.

Comment: @KlausGütter yes on the given editor it's working fine , but on my system this code is always returning Not Palindrome.

Comment: Is this the exact code you run? Are you sure your string "madam" does not contain any invisible special characters?

Answer (score 0):

for finding palindrome, you can use

```
public static void Main()
{
    string s1 = "madams";
    string response = s1==Reverse(s1)?"palindrome":"not palindrome";
    Console.WriteLine(response);
}
public static string Reverse( string s )
{
    char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse( charArray );
    return new string( charArray );
}
```

Ref: [Reverse String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228060/9429059)

Comment: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/ (search for "reverse")

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided runs fine, but you can improve it. At the moment you create numerous new `string` instances each time you add character, because `string`s are immutable.

```
s2 += s1[i];
```

These allocations are expensive. You can check the `string` by comparing the first with the last character, then the second with the second last, or in general index `i` with `text.Length - i - 1`:

```
private bool IsPalindrome(string text)
{
   for (var i = 0; i < text.Length / 2; i++)
   {
      if (text[i] != text[text.Length - i - 1])
         return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```