# Reverse order of string, but keep numbers intact

Tags: c#, .net, string, reverse

I have a string like this:

```txt
1.1.168.192
```

I need to convert it to this, with the numbers intact but the order reversed:

```txt
192.168.1.1
```

This seems like an easy question, but I cant figure it out. I'm trying something within a `for` loop right now but I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: A naive solution: `string.Join(".", input.Split('.').Reverse())`

Comment: @zcoop98 That's about reversing all the characters in a string.  The OP just wants to reverse the order of the numbers between the periods while keeping the numbers the same.

Comment: @juharr Shoot, you're right, I missed that.

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: [Best way to reverse a string in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228038)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thank you so much it saved my life!! It worked. Pure solution. I was trying some dumb for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help:

```
string[] splitted = "1.1.168.192".Split('.');
Array.Reverse(splitted);
string reversed = string.Join(".", splitted);
```

The idea is you can split things by using a char and it creates an array, then reverse it, and then join them by using a char again it will become string again.

Answer (score 0):

you could split your your string and reverse this array and join it together like this:

```cs
string reverseIP(string ip) { // ip = "1.1.168.192"
    string[] ipParts = ip.split('.'); // ["1", "1", "168", "192"]
    Array.Reverse(ipParts);
    
    return String.Join(".", ipParts);
}
```