# C# Error when calling Reverse : System.Linq.Enumerable+ReverseIterator`1[System.Char]

Tags: c#, string, reverse

a quite simple code:

```
string str = "hello  world";
            
Console.WriteLine(str.GetType());

Console.WriteLine("str.Reverse().ToString():");
Console.WriteLine(str.Reverse().ToString());
```

and got the following output:

> System.String
> str.Reverse().ToString():
> System.Linq.Enumerable+ReverseIterator`1[System.Char]

the question is , why there is the 'ReverseIterator`1' error ? thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[`String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0#methods) does not have instance method `Reverse`, it is actually an extension method [`Enumerable.Reverse<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-reverse-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0)))) available on string due to the fact that it implements `IEnumerable<char>`:

```
public sealed class String : ICloneable, 
    IComparable, 
    IComparable<string>, 
    IConvertible, 
    IEquatable<string>, 
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<char>
```

`Reverse` returns `IEnumerable<char>` with underlying implementation missing overload for `ToString` so it outputs type name. I.e. next to lines will have the same output:

```
Console.WriteLine(str.Reverse().ToString());
Console.WriteLine(str.Reverse().GetType());
```

You can reverse string next "quick and dirty" solution:

```
var reversed = new string(str.Reverse().ToArray());
```

Or select one of answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string).

Answer (score 0):

[String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0#methods) does not have instance method `Reverse`. Your code `str.Reverse().ToString()` is actually splitting your string char-by-char and then reversing it using the `Reverse` method in the `Array` instance.

What you can do is manually split your string into a char array, reverse the array using the `Reverse` method in the `Array` instance and then join it using the `Join` method in `String` instance. Something like this:

```
string str = "hello  world";

Console.WriteLine(str.GetType());

// Manually split the string into a char array,
// reverse the array and then join it.
Console.WriteLine("str.ToCharArray().Reverse():");
string NewStr = string.Join("", str.ToCharArray().Reverse());

Console.WriteLine(NewStr);
// Output: "dlrow  olleh"
```

But if you want to stick with the code you wrote then you can do something like this:

```
string str = "hello  world";

Console.WriteLine(str.GetType());

string NewStr = "";
Console.WriteLine("str.Reverse().ToString():");

// Split the string into a char array,
// reverse the char array and append the chars to a new string.
foreach (var i in str.Reverse())
{
    NewStr += i.ToString();
}

Console.WriteLine(NewStr);
// Output: "dlrow  olleh"
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: _"is actually splitting your string char-by-char and then reversing it using the Reverse method in the Array instance"_ - no, it is not, as far as I [can see](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Reverse.cs,25). And [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/String.cs,577)

Comment: @GuruStron I said this just to make it easier for the questioner to understand.