# How to return a text from Controller to View using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to return the content from the controller to the view but for some reason, it doesn't work. I want the text from the "return Contect (....)" to replace the label.
Here is my code from the controller:

```
namespace Assignment.Controllers
{
    public class Q2Controller : Controller
    {
        // GET: Q2
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ValidateInput(string myInput)
        {
 
            string temp = "";
            for (int i = myInput.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                temp += myInput[i].ToString();
            }
            if (temp == myInput)
               return Content("The string is palindrome");
            else
                return Content("The string is not palindrome");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the View:

```
<body>
    <p>Please enter an alphanumeric string:</p>
    <div class="lbl">
        @Html.Label("lblpalindrome", "Is it palidrome?")
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        @Html.TextBox("myInput");
        <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Enter" onclick="ValidateInput()" />
   </div>
</body>

<script>
    function ValidateInput() {
        var result="";
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("ValidateInput", "Q2")",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            data: { myInput: $('#myInput').val() },
            success: function (response.data) {
                $("#lblpalindrome").text(response.data);
            },
            error: function (response.data) {
                alert("An error occurred: " + response.data);
            }

        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I sugest that you use Chrome developer tools (https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/02/28/debugging-best-practices-for-rest-api-consumers/) or equivalent, in order on instect what exactly the server is returning to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also can do this way without server side call :

```js
function ValidateInput()
{
   $("#lblpalindrome").text("Is it palidrome?");
  var input = $('#myInput').val();
  if(input!==null && input!==undefined && input!=='')
    {
      var reverseinput = input.split("").reverse().join("");
      
      if(input==reverseinput)
        {        
            $("#lblpalindrome").text("The string is palindrome");
        }
      else
        {
            $("#lblpalindrome").text("The string is not palindrome");
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <p>Please enter an alphanumeric string:</p>
    <div class="lbl">
      <label id="lblpalindrome">Is it palidrome?</label>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <input type='text' id=myInput>
        <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Enter" onclick="ValidateInput()" />
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're just returning a plain string response, then there's no `data` property in the `response` argument of the `success` handler function. `response` itself is the text value:

```
success: function(response) {
  $("#lblpalindrome").text(response);
},
```

That being said, returning a plain text response is not a good pattern to follow. Use a serialised format as it's more extensible and reliable. In this case I'd suggest using JSON:

```csharp
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ValidateInput(string myInput)
{
  string temp = "";
  for (int i = myInput.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    temp += myInput[i].ToString();
  }
 
  if (temp == myInput)
    return Json(new { message = "The string is palindrome" });
  else
    return Json(new { message = "The string is not palindrome" });
  }
}
```

```js
success: function(response) {
  $("#lblpalindrome").text(response.message);
},
```

This could be taken a step further still by using a common class for the response. In addition, there are [better ways to reverse a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228038/519413) than using a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still doesn't give me an answer back tho.

Comment: Sorry bad english. I tried your suggestions but when I run it, it doesn't return properly the text that I want.

Comment: Try checking the devtools console for errors after making the AJAX request

Comment: The console is clear