# Program to reverse string and make it uppercase?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, icsharpcode

I wrote this program like the title says but it says `system.char[]` for some reason.

```
using System;
public class q2
{
    public static void upperNreverse(string inp)
    {
        char[] inpChar = inp.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(inpChar);
        string inpString = Convert.ToString(inpChar);
        string finalString = inpString.ToUpper();
        Console.WriteLine(finalString);
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the string to convert to uppercase");
        string inp = Console.ReadLine();
        upperNreverse(inp);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `string inpString = Convert.ToString(inpChar);` is converting the `inpChar` array into a string representation of itself. You probably want to iterate over the array and concatenate all of the characters into one `string`.

Comment: Alternatively, try `string inpString = inpChar.ToString();` and see if that helps.

Comment: @Ibrennan208: nope still does'nt work. tried your second comment

Comment: Let me know how it turns out when you try the first comment.

Comment: If you need more help, then perhaps this would help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/csharp-arrays/

Or this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/

Comment: `string inpString = string.Concat(inpChar);`.

Comment: `string inpString = new string(inpChar);` also works

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(new string(inp.ToUpper().Reverse().ToArray()));` would appear to be the simplest

Comment: `Array.Reverse` [does not reverse a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/).

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToString()` is not suitable for converting a char array to a string. Use the constructor `new string(char[])`

Change

```
string inpString = Convert.ToString(inpChar);
```

to

```
string inpString = new string(inpChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
using System;
public class q2
{
    public static void upperNreverse(string inp)
    {
        char[] inpChar = inp.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(inpChar);
        String inpString = new String(inpChar);
        string finalString = inpString.ToUpper();
        Console.WriteLine(finalString);
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the string to convert to uppercase");
        string inp = Console.ReadLine();
        upperNreverse(inp);

    }
}
```

This is `string inpString = Convert.ToString(inpChar);` not the correct format for converting the char[] to string.
Use these code

```
String inpString = new String(inpChar);
```